# Center column with specifying width in table (tabular enviroment)?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, width

I have table that has long headers and I would like to specify width of the column, but also be able to remain it's centred position.

Something like `|c{0.30\textwidth}|`.

It is possible? How to achieve this effect?

Comment: @lockstep : Why is this one marked as duplicate even though it was asked earlier than the question it allegedly duplicates?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You could use the array package. It provides a way add a `\centering` command to a p-colum. Here's a tiny example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}}
first row \\
second row
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The general syntax is `>{command}` before the actual column specifier. `\centering` changes the meaning of `\\`, thus `\arraybackslash` has been used to restore that. Have a look at the `array` [documentation](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/tools/array.pdf) to learn more.

Comment: I would add `\hspace{0pt}` to the column definition in order to allow the first word in a cell to be hyphenated.

Comment: @lockstep: Good addition, because it's a general issue with narrow columns like chosen in the demo example. In that example code, `>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}` would indeed result in a hyphenation.

Answer (score 59):

In addition to Stefans answer: If you use centered columns with a fixed width quite often, you can define a new column type:

```
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
```

The "x" column takes its width as argument. In your document, you would write e.g.

```
\begin{tabular}{cx{3cm}c}
```

EDIT: Thanks to an answer from Ulrike Fischer on the German-speaking forum [mrunix.de](http://mrunix.de/forums/showpost.php?p=309008&postcount=6), I learned that there is still room for improvement: One might want to manually break lines within a cell of a "centered" p-column, but `\newline` doesn't work correctly in this case. Solution: assign the meaning of `\\` (as defined by `\centering`!) to `\newline` within the cell:

```
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
```

Comment: Hey,
sorry for necroing this thread, but this doesn't work for me, for some reason.
I get following error: 
Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (3 cm): `c' used. \end{tabularx}
While this is my tabular environment definition:
\begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth}{| R{0.3\linewidth} | C | C | C |}
where R is basically the same as you have with \raggedleft instead of centering, and C the same as your "x"

Comment: @Aeefire maybe because `C` is already defined, try `y` instead.