# How to create fixed width table columns with text raggedright/centered/raggedleft?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, width

I would like to create a table with some columns' width specified, while the text in those columns should be centered both horizontally and vertically. I found out that

```
\usepackage{array}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | m{5cm} |}
```

vertically centers the text in the last column, but justifies it horizontally (like text in normal paragraphs).

*Update:* With Jake's method, it seems both `\\` and `\hline` cause an error. How to fix it?

Comment: Link to related answer: see [line breaking - What is \arraybackslash doing on my table column?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/387737/250119) for an explanation why `\arraybackslash` is needed.

Answer (score 477, accepted):

A comprehensive solution (based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/center-column-with-specifying-width-in-table-tabular-enviroment/5020#5020)) is to define new column types (say, L, C, and R) that take their width as argument and do the following:

- Issue `\raggedright`, `\centering`, or `\raggedleft` to achieve the desired horizontal alignment,
- Declare `\let\newline\\` to allow to use `\newline` for manual line breaks within a cell (note that `\centering` & friends change the meaning of `\\` -- this is the problem with Jake's  solution),
- Issue `\arraybackslash` (i.e., `\let\\\tabularnewline`) to allow (again) to use `\\` for ending rows,
- Issue `\hspace{0pt}` to allow the first word in a cell to be hyphenated.

In the example below, the new column types are based on (vertically centered) m-columns, but one may use (top- or bottom-aligned) p- or b-columns as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| c | L{3cm} | C{3cm} | R{3cm} |}
foo &
A cell with text that wraps around, is raggedright and allows \newline
    manual line breaks &
A cell with text that wraps around, is centered and allows \newline
    manual line breaks &
A cell with text that wraps around, is raggedleft and allows \newline
    manual line breaks \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works. In this way I don't have to add anything, just use "\\" and "\hline" as normally.

Comment: @Covi: As @Jakes's answer seems to produce errors which are corrected in my answer, please consider to accept my answer instead. ("Accepted" answers are displayed at the top, and the next user facing your problem will perhaps only read the accepted answer.)

Comment: @Jake: +1 for chivalry.

Comment: For anybody's interest: There is an (error free) conflict with the `pdfsync` package, which corrupts the spacing. I took me a while to find this problem...

Comment: One small problem with this solution is that columns using `p` get vertically centered when there are longer `L` columns.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/257166/9075 for more information on the `\newcolumtype` command

Comment: Please note that `LCRJ` column types are defined by the [tabulary](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabulary) package. Just in case someone uses this excellent hint together with `tabulary` and wonders why some other tables break.

Comment: Is there a solution when your journal template is incompatible with the array package? Yes, incompatible with the array package.

Comment: @broncoAbierto Fix the template? More seriously though, post a new question about that if you haven't figured it out.

Comment: Any way to escape the column header from the alignment? Like if I have numerals in the columns that I need right aligned, but the header should be centered. Thanks

Comment: for the other noobs reading this: you HAVE TO specify a width for each column of this new type. Otherwise, you get the usual 27 Latex errors that say absolutely nothing ;)

Comment: Does ``hspace`` in the ``R`` column type do anything? (if it does, there must be something else interfering in my setup, as it does nothing for me)

Comment: How to add multiple rows to the table such that each cell is bordered by lines? Currently, only the columns are bordered by lines.

Comment: The solution appears incompatible with the `colortbl` package while in the `beamer` document class, producing an error.

Comment: If some cell consists of one word that is wider than the fixed column, then that word is shifted down by half a line. How to prevent this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/498203/

Comment: Can we also reduce space in between columns ?

Comment: [In LuaLaTeX the line break will always work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/276154/250119). The problem only happen with other engines (try a code without the patch `\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}}
particular particular
\end{tabular}
`)

Answer (score 77):

The 'm' column type only centers the text vertically; to get it also centered horizontally, you can use the `>{cmd}` syntax, which adds a command before each cell in the specified column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | >{\centering}m{5cm} |}
Abc & Bcd & A long cell with text that wraps around and is centered
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: tabular with column that is horizontally and vertically centered]

As Stefan Kottwitz pointed out in his comment, this can also be be wrapped in a new column type that you can define using

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}
```

Then you can define the above table using

```
begin{tabular}{| c | c | C{5cm} |}
```

Comment: Works, but if there is a `\\ \hline` after the table row, this yields a `misplaced \noalign` error. According to [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35350/18853), `\arraybackslash` is required.

Comment: How to add multiple rows to the table such that each cell is bordered by lines? Currently, only the columns are bordered by lines.

Comment: @Hans - Use `\hline` to draw horizontal lines.

Answer (score 13):

It’s easy peasy to specify the horizontal and vertical alignment of table cells at the same time with `tblr` environment of the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{|Q[l,t,3cm]|Q[c,m,3cm]|Q[r,b,3cm]|}
\hline
 {Top Baseline \\ Left Left} & Middle Center & {Right Right \\ Bottom Baseline} \\
\hline
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can even remove the width settings of the columns to use the natural widths.

Comment: What is the package for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to install *tabularray*?

Comment: Download `tabularray.sty` and `ninecolors.sty` from CTAN: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray and https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ninecolors

Comment: I just came here to say this is BY FAR the best solution, and table package, I've ever seen. LaTeX tables have given me so much grief over the years, and this simple package is delightful. Easy peasy, indeed. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 12):

I found a very different technique that also works:

With the package `ragged2e` you can issue the command `\RaggedRight` outside the `tabular` environment and get ragged right inside p- or m-columns of a tabular environment.

Here is an example document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}
{\RaggedRight
    \begin{tabular}{| c | m{3cm}}
    foo &
A cell with text that wraps around, is raggedright and allows \newline
manual line breaks \\ 
\end{tabular}
}% end of \RaggedRight
\end{document}
```

[image: Eample created with <code>ragged2e</code>]

Comment: How to add multiple rows to the table such that each cell is bordered by lines? Currently, only the columns are bordered by lines.

Comment: @Hans: As usual, using `\hline` between the table rows (delimited by `\\\`)