# Errors with ragged-right justification in tables

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

My main goal is to disable text justification in tables and just have left-aligned text. I've loaded the `array` package and defined a custom `\newcolumntype` like so:

```
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\raggedright}p{#1}}
```

When using this in the `tabular` environment, everything works fine until the last column, when it throws this error:

```
./temp.tex:96: Misplaced \noalign.
\midrule ->\noalign 
                     {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@aboverulesep =\aboverulesep \global \@...
l.96     \midrule

?
```

Using `\begin{tabular}{@{} x{28mm} x{20mm} x{20mm} p{25mm} @{}}` works fine (but throws an underfull \hbox warning) but using `\begin{tabular}{@{} x{28mm} x{20mm} x{20mm} x{25mm} @{}}` throws the error above.

Why am I not allowed to use my custom column type on the last column? It seems as if I'm missing something obvious to a trivial solution.

With `\begin{tabular}{@{} x{28mm} x{20mm} x{20mm} p{25mm} @{}}`:

[image: table with underfull \hbox]

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's a known issue. When you say `\raggedright`, the command `\\` is redefined. This causes no harm until you want to terminate a table row: LaTeX finds the `\\` as defined by `\raggedright` which doesn't mean the same thing as normally in `tabular`. Write

```
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
```

and use `\newline` if you want to terminate a line in one of the cells. Or use your definition and terminate table rows with `\tabularnewline`.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to the answer by egreg - the command `\RaggedRight` from `ragged2e` package does not have this issue.  This works:

```
\usepackage{array},
\usepackage[originalparameters]{ragged2e}  % The option prevents hyphentation rather than making it rare 
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution: add an empty column.  Depending on how you've built your table, you can either make it minimal width (with p{size}, for instance) or just let LaTeX figure it out.  I used both in a recent paper and it fixed this problem.  The only down side is that one of the tables uses \hline and vertical rules, and there's an 'overhang' on the right side of the table.  I said, deal with it, life's short.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.