# how to create a table where a column is text that wraps?

Tags: tables

The basic tabular package seems oriented for short columns, not where text wraps.

What to do when the third column in this case can be multiple lines of text that should wrap?

```
\begin{tabular} {|c|c|c|}\hline 
 Vendor & Website & Description \\ 
 \hline 
Amazon & \href{amazon.com} & long and windy description goes here \\
Avnet  & \href{avnet.com} & blah blah blah ... \\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: There is a `p{<width>}` type column (as opposed to `c`) that formats as paragraph text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a lot this small column definitions for this kind of things --- I hope they can help (and give hints on how to modify them to your tastes):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array, ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{}p{#1\linewidth}<{}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1\linewidth}<{}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{#1\linewidth}<{}}

\newcommand{\longtext}{This is quite a long test, but not so long
as the text you get with \texttt{lipsum}, just to check things out.}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|P{0.3}|}
    \hline
    kind: & \texttt{P}-column & \longtext \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|R{0.3}|}
    \hline
    kind: & \texttt{R}-column & \longtext \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|M{0.3}|}
    \hline
    kind: & \texttt{M}-column & \longtext \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image: Three kind of paragraph blocks]

Normally justified text come out badly in small columns; I normally prefer using `\raggedright` or, better, [`\RaggedRight`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/ms/ragged2e.pdf) for this kind of text.

The `\arraybackslash` it's here to avoid the infamous [`Misplaced noalign` error...](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35348/errors-with-ragged-right-justification-in-tables)