# How to add a newline in a table cell?

Tags: tables, line-breaking

How can I put a new line (line break) within a table cell?  I'm at a loss how to do this.  I'm not using lyx or anything special, just MacTex and texmaker.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The cell needs to be of a paragraph style: either via a `p{<len>}` column specification, or using a `\parbox`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
  Some text & Some more text \\
  \parbox[t]{3in}{Here is some lengthy text \par with a break\strut} &
  Some more text \\
  Some text & Some more text
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{p{3in}l}
  Some text & Some more text \\
  Here is some lengthy text \par with a break\strut &
  Some more text \\
  Some text & Some more text
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Using `\\` alone would not help, since this is redefined inside a `tabular` to define a new line. Of course, depending on the context, it may also be possible to use

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  Some text & Some more text \\
  Here is some lengthy text & Some more text \\
  with a break \\
  Some text & Some more text
\end{tabular}
```

which resembles a newline in one of the cells.

Comment: You can also use \newline. If you want fixed colum widths and different alignments you can use the answer to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12703/how-to-create-fixed-width-table-columns-with-text-raggedright-centered-raggedlef) and use \newline within this.