# long table alignment in fixed size columns

Tags: horizontal-alignment, longtable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fixed width column with text centered/raggedright/raggedleft in tabular?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12703/fixed-width-column-with-text-centered-raggedright-raggedleft-in-tabular)

My longtable has a column with a fixed size, `p{2cm}`. How do I make that column align to the left? It comes out justified.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12703/fixed-width-column-with-text-centered-raggedright-raggedleft-in-tabular -- my solution also works for `longtable`. (You want to replace `m` with `p`.)

Comment: @lockstep I am sorry I don't get it. Your example refers to a tabular environment. Would that work with a longtable as well? Also, should I add the command in the preamble?

Comment: a) Yes b) Load the `array` package and declare the new column type L as I did in the preamble.

Comment: Add `\userpackage{array} \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}` to your document preamble and use `\begin{longtable}{..L{2cm}..}` in your document.

Comment: Seven out of your nine most recent questions have been closed (overall: nine out of twenty -- almost 50%!). Please take a minute to look at what has been criticized about your questions, and try to avoid these flaws in your next questions!