# How to get column alignment in tabularx?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx

When I put `X` in column specifier, how can I define column formatting? How can I get center alignment? Currently I am putting `\centering`, but that is not a proper solution.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\caption{Case studies}
\centering
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{4cm}*{5}{X}}
    \toprule
\centering Nature of unreliability & \centering Sender SST & \centering Receiver SST & \centering Implementation SST &  Retransmission Bound \\


\midrule

Noisy (Single fixed error message) & DSST & DSST & DSST & Unbounded \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\label{case-studies}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Comment: `\centering` is the proper solution. But if you use it in the last column you should use `\tabularnewline` to end the row of the tabular.

Comment: If you want it to apply to the whole column you can use `>{\centering \arraybackslash}X` as it suggests in the tabularx manual.

Comment: Please, clarify if you need to center align only one row or all of them.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please check my answer -- for whatever reason, `>{\centering \arraybackslash}X` does not suffice.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12712/510) to [How to create fixed width table columns with text raggedright/centered/raggedleft?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12703/fixed-width-column-with-text-centered-raggedright-raggedleft-in-tabular) can also be applied in slightly modified form to `X` columns. (Note that omitting `\let\newline\\` will result in text that is not properly centered.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| c | c | Z |}
Abc & Bcd & Cde \\
Abc & Bcd & A long cell with text that is centered \newline
    and allows manual line breaks \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes `\centering` only redefines `\\` not `\newline` so if you need manual breaks you can do as here, or don't use `\arraybackslash` and use `\\` for centering break and `\tabularnewline` for end of table row, or perhaps simplest you can use a blank line to force a new centred parapgraph

Comment: My god what a rubbish package that requires the definition of a new custom class just to center text horizontally.