# Column alignment in ltablex

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularx, ltablex

I tried to apply the method proposed in [How to get column alignment in tabularx?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97180/how-to-get-column-alignment-in-tabularx) to right align cells in a `ltablex`. However I have a problem when the size of the table is just enough for my columns: some cells end up on two lines, with the first one empty. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\footnotesize}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabularx}{\footnotesize}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\footnotesize}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}


\begin{document}

%\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{3pt}

\begin{tabularx}{160pt}{ X  Y  Z }
% head
  \hline 
  Name & 
  Long~name & 
  Name  \\
  & [unit] & [$longunit$]  \\* 
  \hline\hline 
\endhead
% foot
  \hline
\endfoot 
% body
\multirow{3}{1.6cm}{Text on two lines} & 0 & 0 \\*
 & 0 & 0   \\*
 & 0 & 0   \\
\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```

I get this result:

[image: Compilation result]

I found out that removing the `\hspace{0pt}` in the Y and Z column type definition solves the problem, but as it might be useful in other situations I would like to know if there is a better way to deal with this ?

Also, if I uncomment the line that redefined the `tabcolsep`, the Y and Z columns become left aligned again. Is there a way to have right aligned or center columns with a lower `tabcolsep`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linebreak you can fix with

```
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\nobreak\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\nobreak\hspace{0pt}}X}
```

`\tabcolsep` should be set with `\setlength` not `\renewcommand` (but it still behaves oddly here, out of time now...)

Comment: The difference between the two cases (with the setting of `\tabcolsep` and without) seems to lie in the different branches taken by `\ifdim \wd\@tempboxa <\TX@target` in `\TX@endtabularx`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Any news regarding the `\setlength` of `\tabcolsep` ?

Comment: @Don'tpanic been busy,perhaps at the weekend...