# tabularx preamble tweaks // column widths

Tags: tables, tabularx

am using this:
%%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97188/27721

```
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
```

and would like to use (that is, integrate into the above) sth like that:

```
{>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X>{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X}
```

(which is taken from David's [tabularx](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~c603/latex/tabularx.pdf) manual)

how?

**PS:**

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}*{1}{p{\mylengthydate}}*{1}{X}*{1}{Z}@{}}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Expanded the question with proper **MWE** here:

- [How to get alignment finally "right" with tabularx and an image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255299/how-to-get-alignment-finally-right-with-tabularx-and-an-image)

Comment: Have you tried  `{>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}Z>{\hsize=0.5\hsize}Z}`?

Comment: Just use the Z column you have defined?

Comment: Instead of `*{1}{p{\mylengthydate}}*{1}{X}*{1}{Z}`, it's perfectly OK to write `p{\mylengthydate} X Z`.

Comment: @Mico http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22757450#22757450

Comment: @Mico Syntactically, how could I add `{>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}Z>{\hsize=0.5\hsize}Z}` or equivalent to the section before `\begin{document}`? To integrate it with `\newcolumntype` or sth else?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want the `X` column to be three times as wide as the `Z` column -- as well as the `Z` column type being defined as in your query above and there being no whitespace to the left of the first column or to the right of the final column -- you could set up the structure of the `tabularx` environment as follows:

```
begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} p{\mylengthydate} 
                                >{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X 
                                >{\hsize=0.5\hsize}Z @{}}
```

Comment: In more LaTeX sense `>{\setlength\hsize{1.5\hsize}}X` ...

Comment: @Zarko - I feel comfortable with the syntax proposed in the user guide of the `tabularx` package...