# How to create a new line in the table cell

Tags: tables

I am trying to create a table, but the content in the table cell is quite long, so I decided to create a new line for the cells.

But I am not sure how to do that, could someone help me on that? Here is my code:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Multirow table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
\hline
Observation(Species name)  & Likelihood (Limnodynastes peronii Distribution Model)  &Likelihood (Rhinella marina Distribution Model)\\
  \hline
     Observation 1 (Limnodynastes peronii) &0.0712 &0.2699\\
   \hline
    Observation 2 (Rhinella marina) &0.30 &0.013 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: you could use something like [How to create fixed width table columns with text raggedright/centered/raggedleft?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12703)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of possible solutions is using `\multicolumn` with proper parameters. In the second column lines are manually broken, in the third -- automatically, which does not look nice. However, the general idea should be clear. And `p{4cm}` should be rather replaced by a more suitable value.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document   

\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Multirow table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
\hline
Observation(Species name)  & \multicolumn{1}{p{4cm}|}{Likelihood\newline (Limnodynastes peronii\newline Distribution Model) } &\multicolumn{1}{p{4cm}|}{Likelihood (Rhinella marina Distribution Model)}\\
  \hline
     Observation 1 (Limnodynastes peronii) &0.0712 &0.2699\\
   \hline
    Observation 2 (Rhinella marina) &0.30 &0.013 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}


\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Multirow table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
\hline
Observation(Species name)  & Likelihood (Limnodynastes peronii Distribution Model)  &Likelihood (Rhinella marina Distribution Model)\\
  \hline
     Observation 1 (Limnodynastes peronii) &0.0712 &0.2699\\
   \hline
    Observation 2 (Rhinella marina) &0.30 &0.013 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use stacks,  I show your table twice to show the variety possible.  In the first table, the stacks are top aligned (`\Longunderstack`s) whereas in the 2nd table they are vertically centered (`\Centerstack`s).  In the 1st table, they are centered horizontally, whereas they are left aligned in the 2nd table.

The two "set up" lines are needed before entering `tabular`, namely `\edef\tmp{\the\baselineskip}\setstackgap{L}{\tmp}` when using stacks in `tabular`, because `tabular` redefines `\baselineskip`, which is the default inter-baseline spacing for long stacks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\edef\tmp{\the\baselineskip}
\setstackgap{L}{\tmp}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Multirow table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
\hline
Observation(Species name)  & \Longunderstack{Likelihood\\
   (Limnodynastes peronii\\ Distribution Model)}  & 
  \Longunderstack{Likelihood\\ (Rhinella marina \\Distribution Model)}\\
  \hline
     Observation 1 (Limnodynastes peronii) &0.0712 &0.2699\\
   \hline
    Observation 2 (Rhinella marina) &0.30 &0.013 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\leavevmode\bigskip\\
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
\hline
Observation(Species name)  & \Centerstack[l]{Likelihood\\
   (Limnodynastes peronii\\ Distribution Model)}  & 
  \Centerstack[l]{Likelihood\\ (Rhinella marina \\Distribution Model)}\\
  \hline
     Observation 1 (Limnodynastes peronii) &0.0712 &0.2699\\
   \hline
    Observation 2 (Rhinella marina) &0.30 &0.013 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]