# How to obtain a fixed gap between columns in a table?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, width

How can I center a column of a table which is raggedleft/raggedright at a specified position?

Basically the length between *W* and *X*, *X* and *Y* and *Y* and *Z* should be the same, *W* should be raggedright, *Z* should be raggedleft. The positions of *W* and *Z* are already very near to what I want but the columns under them aren't centered...

The first image is what I got already and the second one is my aim.
[image]

[image]

And a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\IfFileExists{MyriadPro.sty}{\usepackage[lf]{MyriadPro}\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}}{\relax}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{tabular}{m{1cm}C{1.3cm}C{1.3cm}R{1cm}}
\textbf{W}& \textbf{X} & \textbf{Y} & \textbf{Z} \\ 
\hline 
\textbf{A n.c.} & 23,2 & 23,2 & 33,4 \\
\textbf{B} & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
\textbf{C} & 7 & 8 & 9 \\ 
\textbf{D} & 10 & 11 & 12 \\ 
\textbf{E} & 13 & 14 & 15 \\ 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Most of the code I got from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12703/how-to-create-fixed-width-table-columns-with-text-raggedright-centered-raggedlef).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm more going towards what you're after than what you currently have...

Specifying a fixed distance *between* columns is best done using the `@{..}` specification. So, for example, one could use `l@{\hspace{1cm}}c` to denote a 1cm gap between a `l`eft and `c`entred column.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{1cm}}c@{\hspace{1cm}}c@{\hspace{1cm}}c}
  \toprule
  \textbf{W} & \textbf{X} & \textbf{Y} & \textbf{Z} \\
  \midrule
  \rlap{\textbf{A n.c.}}\hphantom{23,2} & 23,2 & 23,2 & 33,4 \\
  \textbf{B} & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
  \textbf{C} & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
  \textbf{D} & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
  \textbf{E} & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The additional play with lengths and text in the `tabular` body is to obtain make the columns the same widths in terms of the contents.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I didn't used the additional lines and phantoms. Should I change the title to a more fitting one? And if so what would you suggest?

Comment: @TimS.: If you'd like. How about "How to obtain a fixed gap between columns in a table?"