# Aligning text in a table- right, left or center

Tags: tables

I am trying to align the text in a table, but somehow the first cell with the year (1848) is not aligned. How can I fix this? Another question is: how can I specify if I want to align the text right, left, or centre in different columns {ccc}. How can I also specify the size of the column width? {r(2cm)}r(2cm)

Below is my WE:

```
  %---------------------Preamble---------------%
\documentclass[twoside,b5paper,9.5pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[total={13cm,19.5cm},top=2.5cm,bottom=2.0cm,left=2.0cm,right=2.0cm, includefoot]{geometry} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}          % removes extra spacing between text
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\pagenumbering{gobble}          % Remove page numbers in a section. The counting starts from Introduction
\usepackage{fancyhdr}           % fancy heading style in headers and footers
\usepackage{footnote}           % use with savenotes to show footnotes % footnotemark can be used when you have to use the same footnote twice (to avoid repetition)
\usepackage{graphicx}           % include graphs/ figures  in the file
\usepackage{setspace}           % to set the line spacing in the document
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lscape}             % to write pages in landscape environment
\usepackage{threeparttable}     % to add footnotes to the tables
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}    % to create some space between table caption and table, otherwise there was no space
\captionsetup[table]{skip=5pt}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}     % to underline the text
\providecommand\phantomsection{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[font={small}]{caption}
\let\newfloat\relax
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\floatsetup[figure]{capposition=bottom}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{grffile}            % to avoid printing the figure name (or otherwise, give figure names without spaces)
\usepackage{float}              % figures as 6 (a), 6 (b) etc.
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}  
\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setlength{\bibsep}{3.05pt}     % spacing between different references
\def\bibfont{\scriptsize}       % fontsize of the references
\usepackage[                    
singlelinecheck=false 
]{caption}

%---------------------Document starts here---------------%
\begin{document}            % the document starts here!

\begin{table}[h!]
\scriptsize
\centering
  \caption{Historical milestones in development of animal cell cultures (\cite{butler2004, verma2014})}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}     \toprule
    \textbf{Timeline} & \textbf{Scientist} & \textbf{Achievements} \tabularnewline  
    \midrule
    1878  & Bernard & Physiological state of cells can be maintained after the death of an organism \tabularnewline      \rule{0cm}{0.30cm}
    1885  & Roux  & Maintained chick embryonic cells in warm salt solutions \tabularnewline      \rule{0cm}{0.30cm}
    1989  & Amgen Inc. & Recombinant erythropoietin produced in CHO cells \tabularnewline   
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:history}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is a lot of packages.

Comment: @ Null  yes, I agree. the document is a part of thesis that I am writing. I do not know if there is something redundancy in the packages I used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example using the `threeparttable` package. You alignment problem was caused by the invisible rules, which I replaced with the `\addlinespace` command. I adjusted the value of `\defaultaddspace` so as to obtain the same effect as your invisible rules.

```
\documentclass[twoside,b5paper,9.5pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[total={13cm,19.5cm},top=2.5cm,bottom=2.0cm,left=2.0cm,right=2.0cm, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype} % removes extra spacing between text
\pagenumbering{gobble} % Remove page numbers in a section. The counting starts from Introduction
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\usepackage{lscape} % to write pages in landscape environment
\usepackage{array, threeparttable} % to add footnotes to the tables
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption} % to create some space between table caption and table, otherwise there was no space
\captionsetup[table]{skip=5pt}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

\setlength\defaultaddspace{0.66ex}
%---------------------Document starts here---------------%
\begin{document} % the document starts here!

\begin{table}[h!]
\scriptsize
\captionsetup{font=small}
\setlength\defaultaddspace{0.66ex}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{Historical milestones in development of animal cell cultures (\cite{butler2004, verma2014})}
  \label{tab:history}%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ccm{5cm}@{}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Timeline} & \textbf{Scientist} & \textbf{Achievements} \tabularnewline
    \midrule
    1878 & Bernard & Physiological state of cells can be maintained after the death of an organism \tabularnewline
\addlinespace
    1885 & Roux & Maintained chick embryonic cells in warm salt solutions \tabularnewline
\addlinespace
    1989 & Amgen Inc. & Recombinant erythropoietin produced in CHO cells \tabularnewline
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: your solution works nicely, as I do not have to change a lot in the existing table. But, If I want to have different line spacing in different tables, how can I define that option?

Comment: You have different solutions: first you can change locally the value of `\defauladdspace`. However this requires writing `\addspace` between each row. You also can use the `cellspace` package, which ensures a *minimal*  vertical spacing between a cell and the above and below cells. A thirs solution is the `makecell` package, which allows to *add* a fixed height and depth to all cells in a table. See the documentation of these packages for details.

Comment: I am having difficulties with defining \defaultaddspace locally. can you provide an example please? thanks

Comment: For instance you can move it *inside* the `table` or the `threeparttable` environment, but before `tabular` (where it is used). See my modified answer. If you don't have any environment inside which to put it, enclose it within a pair of braces.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the struts `\rule{0cm}{0.30cm}` should be before the `\tabularnewline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}            % the document starts here!

\begin{table}[h!]
\scriptsize
\centering
  \caption{Historical milestones in development of animal cell cultures (\cite{butler2004, verma2014})}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}     \toprule
    \textbf{Timeline} & \textbf{Scientist} & \textbf{Achievements} \tabularnewline  
    \midrule
    1878  & Bernard & Physiological state of cells can be maintained after the death of an organism \rule{0cm}{0.30cm}\tabularnewline
    1885  & Roux  & Maintained chick embryonic cells in warm salt solutions \rule{0cm}{0.30cm}\tabularnewline      
    1989  & Amgen Inc. & Recombinant erythropoietin produced in CHO cells\rule{0cm}{0.30cm} \tabularnewline   
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:history}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Consider though the possibility of removing all the struts and using `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}` (where you can play with the 1.5) just after `\begin{table}` in order to control the row spacing.

As for how to align the column, use `{l}` or `{r}` instead of `{c}` if you want the columns left or right aligned, respectively.

Finally, about controlling the width of a column you can use `{p{1cm}}` (with this type of column the text is justified as in a normal paragraph; if you need left, right, or center alignment see [How to create fixed width table columns with text raggedright/centered/raggedleft?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12703/how-to-create-fixed-width-table-columns-with-text-raggedright-centered-raggedlef))

Comment: As noted by Andrew in his answer, `\tabularnewline` is not needed, just \\ will do.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way you can make this table.

In any LaTeX table, you set the alignment of the columns in the preamble, e.g., `{rll}`. To specify the width you can use `p{\width}` where `\width` stands for either a measured length with unit (`4cm`) or a LaTeX variable length (`0.5\linewidth`).

The `tabularx` package is ideal for this particular table, because you can specify the first two columns and then use an `X` column to get a right column that fills the remaining space and wraps the text as needed.

Since you are already using `booktabs`, which is designed to implement a specific style of tables with its `\toprule` and `\midrule` commands, it is probably not the best style to add additional rules to the table. You might look at `\addlinespace` from the `booktabs` package.

The `book` class is designed for captions to be placed underneath tables; otherwise the spacing is off. And `\tabularnewline` is not needed in normal tables, only `\\`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{r l X}
\toprule
Timeline & Scientist & Achievements\\
\midrule
1878  & Bernard & Physiological state of cells can be maintained after the death of an organism\\
1885  & Roux  & Maintained chick embryonic cells in warm salt solutions\\
1989  & Amgen Inc. & Recombinant erythropoietin produced in CHO cells\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Historical milestones in development of animal cell cultures}
\label{tab:history}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The spacing for captions above the table could be controlled though with `\usepackage{caption}\captionsetup{aboveskip=3pt}`

Comment: @summer Thanks - the *Chicago Manual of Style*, for one, recommends table captions above the table, so what you suggest would be better.

Comment: @AndrewCashner   I have this code in my preamble to place the captions on the top of the table: \let\newfloat\relax
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}

Comment: @musarithmia Can you please tell how to use `p{\width}` along with `{r l l}`.  I used the following line: `\begin{tabularx}{p{3cm} p{3.5cm} p{7cm}}{c c X}`. I am getting error. Basically I want to have a table with three columns, with each column having different width and different alignment. Can you please help me?

Comment: @Giri With `tabularx` or `tabulary` the first argument is the maximum width of the table, then the specifications for the columns. So, `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ p{1in} c X }` would produce a table as wide as the text block where the first column is formatted like a regular paragraph, 1 inch wide; the second column is centered and is as wide as the content of that column, and the third column `X` fills the remaining width and is formatted like a regular paragraph.

Comment: @Giri You use `p{1in}` in *place* of `l`, `c`, or `r` to specify the width. Try `texdoc latex2e` and look up `tabular`, or check the LaTeX Wikibook. Post a new question on this site if you still have a specific question and we will help!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the bibtex specifications as detailed here: [The 14 BibTeX entry types](https://www.bibtex.com/e/entry-types/).

[image]