# Aligning Text in a Table (various alignments in the column)

Tags: tables, tabularx

I need to set up a table with three columns.

The first two columns have a width of 7.2 cm and the last has a width of 1.5 cm.

I would like text in the first row of the columns to be centred, but then the text in the first and third columns will remain centred, but the second column is aligned to the left.

I tried the tabularx suggestion on [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234246/aligning-text-in-a-table-right-left-or-center), but can't set the column widths, let alone see how I can change the second column to left aligned.

Comment: Could you please add a screenshor of the desired output as well as a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that show what you tried so far?

Comment: Please also clarify: Is ist just the contents of the first row in every column that you want to horizontally center or do you want to horizontally center all rows of a specific column?

Comment: If its the first case, you could use `\multicolumn{1}{c}` of `\makecell` (needs the `makecell`)  package. If it's the second case, you could try with `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{7.2cm}` instead.

Comment: Also, are you sure that our textwidth is larger than 15.9 cm? Otherwise your table will overflow into the right margin.

Comment: 15.9cm + 6\tabcolsep!

Comment: @leandriis here is what I've tried to start with:

`\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\hsize=7.2cm}c|>{\hsize=7.2cm}c|>{\hsize=1.5cm}X}
    \hline
    Column 1 & Column 2 & Col 3\\
    \hline
    The text in this column needs to be centred and allow for text wrapping and will include equations & Text in this column needs to be aligned to the left and needs to allow for text wrapping & no wrap\\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}`

Comment: @C.deHaer: `>{\hsize=7.2cm}c` will not work. Try with  something like `\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{7.2cm}|p{7.2cm}|l}` instead.

Comment: @C.deHaer: With the above mentioned command, the table will be about 17 cm wide. Is you text block wide enough for that?

Comment: @leandriis yes it should be fine. It's an A4 page with narrow margins.

Comment: @leandriis I tried your suggestion and it works for Column 1, but the first row of Column 2 also needs to be centred.

Comment: @C.deHaer: As already mentioned an a previous commant, you can use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 2}` to center one cell in an otherwise differentl aligned column. However, please be aware that this might not work correctly (needs to be adjusted) if the contents of the cell would require a linebreak to fit into the respective column.

Comment: Excellent, but now the | between column 2 and 3 has disappeared.

Comment: `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Column 2}`should work.

Answer (score 1):

Various alignment in tables is very easy with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {Q[7.2cm,c]|Q[7.2cm,l]|Q[1.5cm,c]},
  row{1} = {c}, hlines,
}
  Column 1 & Column 2 & Col 3 \\
  The text in this column needs to be centred and allow for text wrapping and will include equations
           & Text in this column needs to be aligned to the left and needs to allow for text wrapping
                      & no wrap \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]