# Adjusting column size in Latex table

Tags: tables, texmaker, columns, width

I am using the code below to get a simple table but I need to adjust the width of each column.

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centerline{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Group} & \textbf{Count} \\ \hline
1 & 1030 \\ \hline
2 & 425 \\ \hline
3 & 274 \\ \hline
4 & 109 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

I tried using the tabular* as shown below but I get a lot of errors

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centerline{
\begin{tabular*}{.5\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}{|c|c|}}
\hline
\textbf{Group} & \textbf{Count} \\ \hline
1 & 1030 \\ \hline
2 & 425 \\ \hline
3 & 274 \\ \hline
4 & 109 \\ \hline
\end{tabular*}
}
\end{table}
```

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12712/31034

Comment: I already saw that but I did not understand any answer on stack since they seem complicated and I am a beginner. Can you help me with my simple example?

Comment: saying "you get errors" isn't helpful, you should always show the exact error from the  log (I can't test as it is just a fragment, but you have a spurious pair of braces `{|c|c|}` should be `|c|c|`) you should however not use `\centerline` in LaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust the width of columns by using the `p` column type:

```tex
\begin{tabular}{p{2in}p{1in}}
```

The `array` package offers some controlled-width column types, as well, along with the ability to define your own column types.