# How does the \newcolumntype command work?

Tags: tables, columns

I'm a StackExchange and LaTeX newb trying to figure out tables and `tabularx`. Sometimes I copy code but don't actually know what I'm doing or why it works or fails.

Can someone explain to me how the `\newcolumntype` command works and what this one is doing? I got it from the official documentation for `tabularx`. Especially the "`>`" thing, which I don't understand.

Example: `\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\small\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}`

Comment: Everything included in `>{}` is prepended to all the cells in the column `Y`. More info can be found in the `array` documentation.

Comment: run `texdoc array` and read page 2

Comment: As Herbert said, page 2 for the `>{}`, `{}<` syntax, and page 3 for `\newcolumntype`.

Answer (score 51):

The [`array`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package documentation, on pages 2 and 3 has the explanations:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

### Additional explanation

To answer your specific question:

```
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\small\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
```

defines a new type of column called `Y` based on a `X` column (this column type is defined by the `tabularx` package and it is basically a `p{ <width>}` column, where `<width>` is calculated by the package) but typesets the content using `\small` font size and with ragged-right text.

To sum up, `Y` is now a `p{<width>}` column whose contents will be typeset in `\small` font size and ragged-right. And now, instead of the cumbersome

```
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\linewidth}{c>{\small\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xl>{\small\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
 ...
\end{tabularx}
```

you can simply say

```
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\linewidth}{cYlY}
 ...
\end{tabularx}
```

### `\newcolumntype` with arguments

Let's say, as an example, that we need a table with three `p{}` type columns with the following specifications:

- First column: width=4cm, color=(shade of) blue; ragged-left content.
- Second column: width=3cm, color=(shade of) red; ragged-left content.
- First column: width=5cm, color=(shade of) green; ragged-left content.

The best thing here is to define a new column type; `\newcolumntype` also receives parameters (like `\newcommand`), so in this case we need a new type with two parameters: color and width:

```
\newcolumntype{C}[2]{>{\columncolor{#1}\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#2}}
```

And the table format would look like

```
\begin{tabular}{C{red!30}{4cm}C{blue!20}{3cm}C{green!20}{5cm}}
...
\end{tabular}
```

The complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{C}[2]{>{\columncolor{#1}\raggedleft}p{#2}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{C{red!30}{4cm}C{blue!20}{3cm}C{green!20}{5cm}}
Some test text to illustrate the new column type 
  & Some test text to illustrate the new column type 
  & Some test text to illustrate the new column type 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

### `\arraybackslash`

As for `\arraybackslash`, the `\raggedright`, `\raggedleft`, and `\centering` declarations redefine `\\` in a way which conflicts with its use in a `tabular` or `array` environments. The command `\arraybackslash` (implemented in `array` and `tabularx`) restores the meaning of `\\` for use in `array` and `tabular` (you would only need `\arraybackslash` for the last column).

Comment: How to define a new type that combine the features of math-mode and auto line break? I have tried `\newcolumntype{Y}{>{$}X<{$}}`, but it will not work.