# Can I use \newcolumntype in conjunction with \si?

Tags: tables, siunitx

In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/257128/92298) question, we learn how to use the `array` package to have an array column in math-mode:

```
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}
```

However, for a table of symbols (with units), it would be convenient if I could do the same with `\si{...}`. However, neither

```
\newcolumntype{U}{>{\si{}l<{}}}
```

nor

```
\newcolumntype{U}{>{\si\{}l<{\}}}
```

seem to work (I tried escaping the `{` in that version), when I try it with this table:

```
\begin{tabular}{U}
\newton\per\meter
\end{tabular}
```

I get the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\newton ->\ERROR
l.29 \newton
\per\meter
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

for every unit used. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `siunitx` package no longer provides an `s`-type column for this purpose, because in general units should be in column headers. The `collcell` package can also be used to achieve the same effect

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{collcell}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ls>{\collectcell\si}c<{\endcollectcell}}
1 & \newton & \newton \\
2 & \metre  & \metre  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This can all then be wrapped in a new column type if you want ...

Comment: Why would you deprecate that? I agree that numerical tables should have their units in the column header, but a table of specs or a table of symbols such as often found in theses is definitely a valid use case for the `s` column.

Comment: @Sanchises Largely because it _can_ be covered using `collcell` with no issues

Answer (score 5):

That column type already exists, it is called

```
 s
```

You cannot pickup arguments from columns like you attempt, there you'll need sneaky tricks or use a package (who's name eludes me) which can collect the contents of each cell in a column and give them to a macro

Note that: As of `siunitx` version 3 the `s` colums has need deprecated, see the new `siunitx` manual.