# Left justified, fixed width columns in table not working correctly

Tags: tables

Thanks to this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12703/how-to-create-fixed-width-table-columns-with-text-raggedright-centered-raggedlef) I can create left justified fixed width columns in my table. However, I would like to ask if anyone else has encountered the problems with the last column not working as it should, for example:

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Device technical specifications summary.}
\begin{tabular}{|R{3cm}|R{2cm}|R{2cm}|R{2cm}|R{3cm}|}
\hline
~ & Samsung Galaxy Pocket Neo & Samsung S3 Mini & Vodafone Smart4 Mini & Google (Asus) Nexus 7 (2012) \\
\hline
CPU Speed [MHz] & 850 & 1000 & 1300  & 1200 \\
\hline
CPU Type & 1 Core & 2 Core Coretex-A9 & 2 Core Cortex-A7 & 4 Core Cortex-A9 \\
\hline
RAM [MB] & 512 & 1024 & 512 & 1024 \\ 
\hline
Release Year & 2013 & 2012 & 2014 & 2012 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{Device technical specifications summary}
\end{table}
```

Everything works fine with
`\begin{tabular}{|R{3cm}|R{2cm}|R{2cm}|R{2cm}|p{3cm}|}`

But if as it was set out above, I get:

> Errors: ./contents/Chap-6.tex:40: Misplaced \noalign. [\hline]

i.e. giving me problems starting with the first \hline.

Any advice?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm sorry, but I get no error. Please make a full example.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I can compile this table after adding the necessary stuff around it. Off-topic: The `\label` should be placed rather immediately after `\caption`, not some lines later

Comment: How is the `R` column type defined?

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:  (copied the column types verbatim from the link you provided, which I presume is what you did)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Device technical specifications summary.\label{Device technical specifications summary}}
\begin{tabular}{|R{3cm}|R{2cm}|R{2cm}|R{2cm}|R{3cm}|}
\hline
~ & Samsung Galaxy Pocket Neo & Samsung S3 Mini & Vodafone Smart4 Mini & Google (Asus) Nexus 7 (2012) \\
\hline
CPU Speed [MHz] & 850 & 1000 & 1300  & 1200 \\
\hline
CPU Type & 1 Core & 2 Core Coretex-A9 & 2 Core Cortex-A7 & 4 Core Cortex-A9 \\
\hline
RAM [MB] & 512 & 1024 & 512 & 1024 \\ 
\hline
Release Year & 2013 & 2012 & 2014 & 2012 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I forgot to add: `\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft}m{#1}}` above my table in the question. I don't really see what is so different from `\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}` except for the newline part. Anyways, it worked! Thanks!

Comment: @DanielS The `\arraybackslash` bit is crucial; I don't think ``\let\newline\\`` does any good (just avoid using `\newline` anywhere).