# Globally enable hyphenation for the first word in a paragraph

Tags: hyphenation

how can I globally enable hyphenation for the first word in a paragraph? A manual workaround is to add `\hspace{0pt}` in front of the corresponding word, so that it is not counted as first word, but it would be very good to have a global solution for this. Any ideas?

Kindest regards,
Mil

Comment: Do you have so long words or so narrow columns that this is necessary in *every* paragraph?

Comment: Not that many, but a long document with many enough instances that I was thinking about a smooth, global solution. Also this is especially problematic in tables. I realize that for every first word in a cell, the problem can be solved with >{\hspace{0pt}}; but if I have multiple paragraphs in a cell, this solution is also not satisfying...

Comment: It is hard to imagine that you ever want to hyphenate the first word of a paragraph in the main text? In table columns yes (but that can be specified) doing it in the main text is harder. Or use luatex where this is the default behaviour.

Comment: Perhaps he's writing an article on [Hubert Blaine Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff, Sr.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubert_Blaine_Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff,_Sr.)

Comment: @Psychonaut Gesundheit!!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: :D :D :D

Comment: Indeed the document is written in German – so lots of funny, long words that are to be dealt with. ;)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Could you elaborate on how 'that can be specified'?  I am interested in hyphenation in margin notes.

Comment: Can anyone explain (or point to some external resource about) why that is disabled / hard / bad to do?

Comment: @Andreas It is almost certainly an accidental artefact of the implementation, but frozen now as TeX-the-program is frozen apart from major bugs. LuaTeX, which is not so tied by historical compatibility has changed this so the first word is hyphenated.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're currently compiling your document with pdfLaTeX. If that's the case, I suggest you switch to **LuaLaTeX**. LuaLaTeX is able to hyphenate the first word of every paragraph without the user having to specify anything special.