# table only automatically breaks multiple words

Tags: tables, longtable, glossaries, hyphenation, glossaries-extra

When creating a custom glossary (nomenclature) with a longtable, the system only uses automatic word braking for cells with more than one word.
The column is a `p{...}`-column and it works flawlessly in cells with more than one word.
When I do manual word hyphenation via `\-` the correct line break is being created.
For cells with more than one word the hyphenation is placed automatically.

Update:
As suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/276161/239607) compiling with LuaLaTeX solves the problem although I'm not happy with it. I also don't understand why the solution given by @DavidCarlisle didn't work.

Update 2:
Problem is solved. The word being the first word in the paragraph was indeed the problem. Because I was defining a glossary style I had to add `\hspace*{0pt}`to the template of the column instead of the column definition. In my case this means that

```
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
    \boldmath\ensuremath{\glossentrysymbol{##1}}
    & \glstarget{##1}{\hspace*{0pt}\glossentryname{##1}} %
    & \glossentrydesc{##1}
    & \glsentryunit{##1}\tabularnewline
 }%
```

works, while

```
\setglossarystyle{long4col}% base this style on the list style
 \renewcommand{\glsgroupskip}{}%avoids grouping the elements by alphabetical order
 \renewenvironment{theglossary}{% Change the table type --> 4 columns
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \begin{longtable*}{>{\centering}p{.1\textwidth} >{\arraybackslash\hspace*{0pt}}p{.225\textwidth} p{.475\textwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.1\textwidth}}}%
  {\end{longtable*}}%
```

did not work.

Comment: tex never hyphenates the first word of a paragraph: load array package then use `>{\hspace{0pt}}p{..}` so there is a zero width space before the word

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have just tried your suggestion. Unfortunately it does not work as it should.

Comment: @Pauluuus - A quick follow-up on David Carlisle's comment. Formally, each cell in a tabular structure consists of one or more paragraphs; even a cell with a single word constitutes a paragraph. pdfTeX and XeTeX *never* hyphenate the first "object" (usually a word) in a paragraph. (Hence the advice to insert `\hspace{0pt}`, to ensure that the first word in the cell isn't the first object.) If you're free to use Lua(La)TeX, a nice side benefit of making the switch is that even the first word of a paragraph can get hyphenated withouth having to go through various contortions.

Comment: @Pauluuus - Please edit your posting to provide more detail on what exactly you're doing.

Comment: @Mico thank you for the answer. I had just found one of your previous comments on another question and updated my question.

Comment: @Pauluuus - What about LuaLaTeX aren't you happy with? (LuaLaTeX is, with few exceptions, pretty much a superset of pdfLaTeX. If a document compiles without errors under pdfLaTeX, it should compile -- subject, possibly, to some minor adjustments -- under LuaLaTeX as well.) Regarding David Carlisle's suggestion to change `p{...}` to `>{\hspace{0pt}}p{...}` -- what exactly isn't working? Are you receiving error and/or warning messages? If so, what do they say? Incidentally, did you make sure to load the `array` package?

Comment: @Mico I do not have a problem with LuaLaTeX. I just don't like not understanding a problem and just avoiding it.

Comment: @Pauluuus - I would *not* say that LuaTeX "just avoids" the problem. Rather, I'd say that the setting of TeX (subsequently preserved in pdfTeX and XeTeX) of never hyphenating the very first word of a paragraph was a bug that, once discovered, was declared to be a feature. A rather ugly feature, if you ask me, one which requires a kludgy workaround. LuaTeX finally made the (in my view) courageous choice to no longer support this "feature".