# pass p-width of table column to multirow width for automatic line break

Tags: tables, multirow

Given the following table:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{booktabs, siunitx, multirow}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm}lSS}
        \toprule
        & a & x & y \\ \midrule
        \multirow{2}{=}{entdimensionalisiert} & abc & 0,00 & 20,95  \\
        & def & 0,004 & 0,7 \\ \midrule
        \multirow{2}{=}{normalisiert} & abc & 0,00& 20,95  \\
        & def & 1,00 & 175,00 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}   

\end{document}
```

How can I pass the width of the p-column to both multirows, so that the text inside each multirow can have automatic line breaks accordingly?
Instead of `*`as width information tried `=`, yet of no avail.

Comment: the first word of a paragraph does not hyphenate by default so there would be no line breaking whatever width was passed in unless you put `\hspace*{0pt}`  to allow hyphenation.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information, I will try my luck with your solution and will give feedback once I tried it.

Comment: I tried the starred hspace in different positions, but unfortunately with no different result than without it. So the words still didn't hyphenate even with the multirow width set to 0pt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Now is considered OP comments. Added is solution which use `LuaLaTeX` engine for compiling MWE. It enables to hyphenate also the first word in cell's content.

Use of the `siunitx` package for `S` columns can be simple as you use in your MWE: just `S` without any options anticipate writing a simple numbers with default number of integer and decimal digits in number. However package is much more powerful. It enable to specify (as options) number of integers and decimals: `table-format=<number of  integer digits>.<number of  decimal digits>`  (an elementary option), numbers rounding, adding symbols, etc. For details see package documentation. It is illustrated with many examples.

Use of `\multirow{2}{=}{...}` is right way, however you MWE compiling by `pdfLaTeX` doesn't support hyphenation of the first word in cells' text. Problem you can solve on two ways:

- by inserting of hyphenation points `\-` in words as is done in in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ p{19mm} l S[table-format=1.3] S[table-format=3.2] }
        \toprule
        & a & {x} & {y} \\ \midrule
\multirow{2}{=}{entdimen\-sionalisiert} 
        & abc & 0,00 & 20,95  \\
        & def & 0,004 & 0,7 \\ \midrule
\multirow{2}{=}{normalisiert} 
        & abc & 0,00& 20,95  \\
        & def & 1,00 & 175,00 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- or by adding package `babel` to the MWE and than compile by `LuaLaTeX`:

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}   % <---

\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ p{17mm} l S[table-format=1.3] S[table-format=3.2] }
        \toprule
        & a & {x} & {y} \\ \midrule
\multirow{2}{=}{entdimensionalisiert}
        & abc & 0,00 & 20,95  \\
        & def & 0,004 & 0,7 \\ \midrule
\multirow{2}{=}{normalisiert}
        & abc & 0,00& 20,95  \\
        & def & 1,00 & 175,00 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I read [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/276161/244141) that switching from PDFLaTeX to LuaLaTeX allows the hyphenation of first words in paragraphs and gave it a try. With this I could reproduce your results. In addition you don't even have to specify hyphenation points (to have correct hyphenation points I added the babel package with the ngerman option), then the result was as desired/what I was looking for. Maybe you want to add these suggestions to your answer, then I could mark it as the correct one.

Comment: @Lukas, thank you for comment. Fone!

Comment: You're welcome. If you don't mind, could you elaborate why you specified the S-type columns and what this definitions (table-format 1.3 and table format 3.2) mean, I tried to understand the siunitx-documentation but couldn't figure it out by myself unfortunately.

Comment: @Lukas, see edited answer. Added is short note about `siunitx`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the new `tabularray` package ([CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray)).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{p{1.7cm}lSS}
    \toprule
    & a & x & y \\ \cmidrule{2-4}
    \SetCell[r=2]{t} entdimensionalisiert & abc & 0,00 & 20,95  \\
    & def & 0,004 & 0,7 \\ \midrule
    \SetCell[r=2]{t} normalisiert & abc & 0,00& 20,95  \\
    & def & 1,00 & 175,00 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tblr} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image: output table]

I have increased the width to `1.7cm`, because the text "entdimensionalisert" would otherwise span 3 lines.

The `tabularray` equivalent of `\multirow{2}` is `\SetCell[r=2]`. The width is automatically taken from the table columns definition.

**Note**

This has to be compiled with LuaLaTex to allow hyphenation of the first word in a paragraph.

Comment: unfortunately when I copy your MWE both words are not hyphanated and span a single line each (and are written beyond the cells to their respective right)

Comment: I read [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/276161/244141) that switching from PDFLaTeX to LuaLaTeX allows the hyphenation of first words in paragraphs and gave it a try. With this I could reproduce your results.

Comment: That's right, I compiled this with LuaLaTeX. Did not know, that it makes a difference with hyphenation.