# How to center and wrap text in cells of tables

Tags: tables

I would like to get the following in Latex (without the table borders):

[image]

Here's my (incorrect) code:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \begin{tabular}{c c p{10 cm}}
    $\langle 0 \lvert \phi(x)\phi(y)\lvert 0 \rangle$ & = & the amplitude\newline for a particle to propagate from $y$ to $x$\newline (in the Heisenberg picture).
  \end{tabular}
```

This produces the following (ignore the '4'):

[image]

Can you suggest the correct code?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Have you seen http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12703/how-to-create-fixed-width-table-columns-with-text-raggedright-centered-raggedlef

Comment: Yes. But, I want the item number 1 centered not in the left center of the table, but on the upper left corner.

Comment: @failexam - How about `\begin{tabular}[t]{c c p{10 cm}}`?  Note the `[t]`.

Comment: but you said *ignore the '4'*.... perhaps you want `\begin{tabular}[t]....`

Comment: @ Arash. This places the item number in the lower left corner, not the upper left corner. I want the item number in the upper left corner.

Comment: @cmhughes. Sorry! My bad! I meant 'replace 4 with 1'.

Comment: @failexam - Not for me with this: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c c p{10 cm}}
    $\langle 0 \lvert \phi(x)\phi(y)\lvert 0 \rangle$ 
    & = & the amplitude\newline 
          for a particle to propagate from $y$ to $x$\newline
          (in the Heisenberg picture).
  \end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}`

Comment: @ Arash. I get my problem now. I actually used the following. `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}\begin{document} \begin{enumerate} \item \begin{tabular}[t]{c c C{10 cm}} $\langle 0 \lvert \phi(x)\phi(y)\lvert 0 \rangle$ & = & the amplitude\newline for a particle to propagate from $y$ to $x$\newline (in the Heisenberg picture). \end{tabular} \end{enumerate} \end{document}`.

Comment: @failexam - Sorry, I misunderstood your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the best solution, but `adjustbox` can help to align different kind of boxes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,array, adjustbox, lipsum}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \adjustbox{frame, valign=t, center}{\begin{tabular}{c c C{6cm}}
              $\langle 0 \lvert \phi(x)\phi(y)\lvert 0 \rangle$ & = & the amplitude\newline for a particle to propagate from $y$ to $x$\newline(in the Heisenberg picture).
        \end{tabular}}
        \item Some other text
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update: `frame` inner margins and `tabular` inside `adjustbox`**

From OP's comment, it seems some larger inner margin is needed inside previous `frame`.

`adjustbox` offers option `margin` (always placing it before `frame`) which fixes inner box margins. This option accepts one, two or four values for setting all margins, horizontal and vertical or left, bottom, right and top margin. If only some margin between top line and first inner text line, option could be `margin=0 0 0 2ex`. In next code only two values are used.

Apart from this, `adjustbox` also offers special syntax for specific environments, like `tabular`. Therefore an option like `tabular=ccc` means that second parameter will have a three tabular structure. It saves some typing. This option can be used with `\adjustbox` command or with `adjustbox` environment. In first case an additional `\\` must be added after last tabular line.

Following code shows all three possible declarations:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,array, adjustbox, lipsum}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \adjustbox{margin=0ex 2ex, frame, valign=t, center}
          {\begin{tabular}{c c C{6cm}}
              $\langle 0 \lvert \phi(x)\phi(y)\lvert 0 \rangle$ 
              & = & 
              the amplitude\newline for a particle to propagate 
                 from $y$ to $x$\newline(in the Heisenberg picture).
           \end{tabular}}
    \item \adjustbox{margin=0ex 2ex, frame, valign=t, center, 
          tabular={c c C{6cm}}}{
              $\langle 0 \lvert \phi(x)\phi(y)\lvert 0 \rangle$ 
              & = & 
              the amplitude\newline for a particle to propagate 
                 from $y$ to $x$\newline(in the Heisenberg picture).\\}
    \item \begin{adjustbox}{margin=0ex 2ex, frame, valign=t, center,  
                  tabular={c c C{6cm}}}
              $\langle 0 \lvert \phi(x)\phi(y)\lvert 0 \rangle$ 
              & = & 
              the amplitude\newline for a particle to propagate 
                 from $y$ to $x$\newline(in the Heisenberg picture).
          \end{adjustbox}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I center the lines of the third box? And also how I center the entire table as a whole across the page?

Comment: Alright. The following code centers the line of the third box: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array, adjustbox}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item\adjustbox{valign=t}
            {\begin{tabular}{c c C{7 cm}}
              $\langle 0 \lvert \phi(x)\phi(y)\lvert 0 \rangle$ & = & the amplitude\newline for a particle to propagate from $y$ to $x$\newline (in the Heisenberg picture).
            \end{tabular}}`.

Comment: Now, just tell me how to center the table as a whole?

Comment: @failexam: Updated answer with `adjustbox` `center` option, which works if your `tabular` is not longer than the rest of line. `10cm` for third column was too long. Suppres `frame` option for the final result. New `C` column type (from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12712/1952) centers the contents of third column.

Comment: Please give a way to slightly increase the spacing between the top line of the frame and the first line of text. That is, I need to increase the top margin of the box.

Comment: @failexam: Do you want the box? I just printed it to show tabular box dimenssions compared to linewith and to show that it was centered.

Answer (score 1):

If you add

Edit:
  \usepackage{array}

```
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} %% horizontal centering
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}} %% vertical centering
```

in your preamble.

Than you can choose `P{10cm}` or `M{10cm}` instead of `p{10cm}`.

Comment: You should to mention, that for your solution that package `array` is needed.

Comment: Thanks I wasn't 100% sure, so i didn't want to give to much code.