# \cellcolor extent slightly off when \multicolumn also in use

Tags: tables, color

I am trying to color-code cells of a large matrix that may either contain a number or a symbol.  (MWE at end.)  The numbers are supposed to be flush right within their cell, but the symbols are supposed to be centered.  The normal way to do this is with `\multicolumn`.  I find that this causes the colored box drawn by `\cellcolor` to extend not quite as far left as it should — sometimes.  The "Wrong on the left" section of the screenshot below shows this problem; look closely where the red arrow points.

I tried to fix this by using some `\hfill` hackery instead of `\multicolumn`, but that had even worse effects; now the colored boxes consistently don't extend all the way to the *right*.  The "Wrong on the right" section of the screenshot below shows this problem; there are no red arrows because it's not at all subtle.

How do I get the cell background boxes to be consistently all the same size?

Note 1: What I really want is for all of the data cells to be exactly the same width regardless of their contents.

Note 2: The real table (that the MWE is cut down from) is machine-generated, so I don't care how ugly the markup gets.

Note 3: The "symbols" in this MWE are `<` and `1`.

[image: screenshot of MWE, showing two different ways the background boxes can be the wrong size]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
\begin{document}

\section*{Wrong on the left}

\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{6pt}}r@{\hspace{6pt}}rrr}
& (size) & aaa & bbb & ccc \\
Aaaa aaaa & $5\,130$ &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{blue!75}$1$} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{blue!10}\color{black!50}$<$} &\cellcolor{blue!26}$.01$ \\
Bbbb bbbb & $7\,402$ &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{blue!10}\color{black!50}$<$} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{blue!75}$1$} &\cellcolor{blue!33}$.08$ \\
Cccc cccc & $1\,336$ &\cellcolor{blue!26}$.01$ &\cellcolor{blue!33}$.08$ &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{blue!75}$1$} \\
\end{tabular}

\section*{Wrong on the right}

\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{6pt}}r@{\hspace{6pt}}rrr}
& (size) & aaa & bbb & ccc \\
Aaaa aaaa & $5\,130$ &\cellcolor{blue!75}$1$\hfill\hbox{} &\cellcolor{blue!10}\color{black!50}$<$\hfill\hbox{} &\cellcolor{blue!26}$.01$ \\
Bbbb bbbb & $7\,402$ &\cellcolor{blue!10}\color{black!50}$<$\hfill\hbox{} &\cellcolor{blue!75}$1$\hfill\hbox{} &\cellcolor{blue!33}$.08$ \\
Cccc cccc & $1\,336$ &\cellcolor{blue!26}$.01$ &\cellcolor{blue!33}$.08$ &\cellcolor{blue!75}$1$\hfill\hbox{} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Getting the bounds of `\cellcolor` right is a common problem. It doesn't adapt to differing column separators, so the `@{\hspace{6pt}}` throws it off. A workaround is to append the horizontal space to the preceding column, rather than modifying the column separation (use `<` instead of `@` in your tabular specification).

As for making all the data cells the same size, I'd recommend defining a new column type, `R`, to set the width for all data columns (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12712/89497)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{0.25in}}
\begin{document}

\section*{Correct on both}

\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{6pt}}r<{\hspace{6pt}}RRR}
& (size) & aaa & bbb & ccc \\
Aaaa aaaa & $5\,130$ &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{blue!75}$1$} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{blue!10}\color{black!50}$<$} &\cellcolor{blue!26}$.01$ \\
Bbbb bbbb & $7\,402$ &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{blue!10}\color{black!50}$<$} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{blue!75}$1$} &\cellcolor{blue!33}$.08$ \\
Cccc cccc & $1\,336$ &\cellcolor{blue!26}$.01$ &\cellcolor{blue!33}$.08$ &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{blue!75}$1$} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: correct on both]

Answer (score 2):

The package `nicematrix` has tools designed to address that kind of problem.

In the code of your first MWE, I have loaded `nicematrix` and replaced `{tabular}` by `{NiceTabular}` with the key `color-inside` (alias: `colortbl-like`).

The output is directly as expected (because, with `nicematrix`, the colored panels are drawn with PGF/Tikz and not with the mechanism of `colortbl`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{l@{\hspace{6pt}}r@{\hspace{6pt}}rrr}[color-inside]
& (size) & aaa & bbb & ccc \\
Aaaa aaaa & $5\,130$ &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{blue!75}$1$} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{blue!10}\color{black!50}$<$} &\cellcolor{blue!26}$.01$ \\
Bbbb bbbb & $7\,402$ &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{blue!10}\color{black!50}$<$} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{blue!75}$1$} &\cellcolor{blue!33}$.08$ \\
Cccc cccc & $1\,336$ &\cellcolor{blue!26}$.01$ &\cellcolor{blue!33}$.08$ &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{blue!75}$1$} \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Moreover, if there are several adjacent cells with exactly the same color, you won't see thin white lines between the cells, whatever PDF viewer you use.