# Missing table borders when using tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx

I'm using `tabularx` with this solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12712 to achieve right alignment in a variable column width based on content size with linebreaks.

I would like the result to look like this:
[image: Table]

The problem is the border between `X | X` columns is missing:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}    %% tables with auto size
\usepackage{array}   %% tables content alignment
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X | R{2cm} | R{2cm} |}
      \hline
      Column1 & Column2 & Column3 & Column4 \\ \hline
      a & Some Value & This is a very long right-aligned text that should break automatically & This is a very long right-aligned text that should break automatically \\ \hline
      b & Some Value & Shorter right-aligned text & Shorter right-aligned text \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I ran your test file and all the vertical rules appear

Comment: This is the 'usual PDF viewer does not show lines' issue eventually. Zoom in and the rules appear, most likely

Comment: Ugly, vertical lines on my system, too, but there is no top rule due to missing `\hline` after the table preamble (i.e. before `Column1`). Use `booktabs`in stead and get rid of the vertical lines.

Comment: Yes! Opening the PDF file in a different PDF viewer helped. The missing `\hline` was a typo. But I realized the table headers are still aligned left. Is it possible to align them center? If this is presented as an answer with mentioning the PDF Viewer problem I will gladly accept it.

Comment: @JoudicekJouda: Well, `X` does not center, neither does `R`

Comment: `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{heading}`  (or `|c|` for the first column)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Is it possible to use `\multicolumn` with tabularx? Can you please show a sample for first row (heading) centering only?

Answer (score 2):

to answer the question about headings asked in comments, you can over-ride the right alignment using `\multicolumn{1}{c}` or just simply using  `\centering` since all the columns are `p` (or equivalently, `X`) columns so parboxes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}    %% tables with auto size
\usepackage{array}   %% tables content alignment
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{center}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X | R{2cm} | R{2cm} |}
      \hline
\centering\bfseries
      Column1 & 
\centering\bfseries
Column2 &
\centering\bfseries
Column3 &
\centering\bfseries
Column4 \tabularnewline \hline
      a & Some Value & This is a very long right-aligned text that should break automatically & This is a very long right-aligned text that should break automatically \\ \hline
      b & Some Value & Shorter right-aligned text & Shorter right-aligned text \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{center}

\end{document}
```