# Horizontal Line In Scientific work Place

Tags: horizontal-alignment, scientific-workplace

How To Insert Horizontal Line In Scientific Work Place ? like This

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what you mean by "Up and Down Horizontal Line".

Answer (score 3):

There are several possibilities to achieve that:

1. using a tabular(table) and a newcolumntype from

   Here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12712/127845

   Which allows a column like the `p{<width>}` column but centered `C{<width>}`. So using a table and tabular one can get as MWE

   ```
    \documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{array,booktabs}

    \newcoumntype{C}][1]{%
     >{ \centering\ket\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

    \begin{document}

    \thispagestyle{empty}

    \vspace*{0pt}
    \begin{table}
      \centering
      \begin{tabular}{C{1\textwidth}
        \toprule[3ex]
        {\LARGE Musterklausur Nr.1 } \\[2ex]
        {\large L\"osungsvorschlag   } \\[3ex]
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \vfill

    \end{document}
   ```
2. using the `tcolorbox`package one could adjust the frame and spacing

   ```
   \usepackage{tcolorbox}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{tcolorbox}[%
     boxrule=0pt,        % width of all parts of the frame
     toprule=2pt,        % width of top part frame   
     bottomrule=2pt,     % width of bottom part frame
     top=3ex,            % vspace between content and frame top
     bottom=3ex          % vspace between content and frame bottom
     after=\vspace{3ex}, % set space after box
     arc=0pt,            % more or less rounded corners (now sharp)
     oversize            % make it a bit more then textwidth
     ]
     \centering
     {\LARGE Musterklausur Nr.1 } \\[2ex]
     {\large L\"osungsvorschlag   }
   \end{tcolorbox}

   \end{document}
   ```

The color of the box and frame can be changed with the keys `colback` and `colframe`. There are a lot of possibilities explained in the tcolorbox documentation:

http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf)

Comment: Don't you think you crack a nut with a sledgehammer using `tcolorbox`?

Comment: Well, I do admit its a bit of an overkill perhaps. On the otherhand it does the job in a not workaroundish fashion, if you know what I mean.

Comment: Using a `table` seems to be wrong here.

Comment: Another thing, it should be `{\Large Wombat}` or even `{\Large Wombat\par}`. Those are switches that don't take an argument. Unfortunately done wrong by many and so it carries on an on.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Good point, changed that according to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

For those rules around the title (I assume you mean them) you can use `\rule{<width>}{<height}`. For example `\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}`.