# Creating a table in Latex like this?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I want to create a table like this using Latex[image: I need to do a table as in Figure]

My code is, but I do not know how can make the second and third row in a table?

```
\begin {table}[ ]
\caption {The available bandwidth is divided into PRBs}          
\label{tab:The available bandwidth is divided into PRBs} 

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c |c |c |c |c |c |} 
\hline
 Bandwith & & & & & & \\ 
 (MHz) & 1.25 & 2.5 & 5.0 & 10.0 & 15.0& 20.0\\ 
 \hline 
 Subcarrier   & & & & & & \\   
 bandwidth (kHz)  & & & & & & \\  

 \hline
 Physical resource block   & & & & & & \\ 
 (PRBs) bandwidth (kHz)   & & & & & & \\  
 \hline 
 Number of available &   &   &   &   &   &  \\ 
 PRBs & 6 & 12 & 25 & 50 & 75 & 100\\ 
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{center}
 \end {table}
```

Do you have any ideas how to tex this layout?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to the site.  WHat have you tried so far?  Post some code.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks a lot for your comment. I added the code again. But I do not know how can I write the second and third row. Do you have any ideas for this problem? Thanks

Comment: @user3727281: Please read an introductory text on LaTeX: It will show you the possibility of `\multicolumn{6}{c|}{15}` most likely in the second and similar in the 3rd row

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what exactly is your problem with typesetting this table in LaTeX, but I tried to reproduce all the features of your example. This code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.0}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries}C{5cm}|C{1cm}|C{1cm}|C{1cm}|C{1cm}|C{1cm}|C{1cm}|}
    \hline
    Bandwidth (MHz) & 1.25 & 2.5 & 5.0 & 10.0 & 15.0 & 20.0 \\
    \hline
    Subcarrier bandwidth (kHz) & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{15} \\
    \hline
    Physical resource block (PRB) bandwidth (kHz) & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{180} \\
    \hline
    Number of available PRBs & 6 & 12 & 25 & 50 & 75 & 100 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

compiles to this table:

[image]

Some notes on the commands I used:

- In the first column, you want to have central alignment, but at the same time automatically wrap in case the lines get too long. I follow [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12712/103046) in defining a new column type `C` that gets a width (like in `C{5cm}`) but is centrally aligned. The same column type I use for the other columns, to have the numbers centered but with a fixed width.
- To extend a single cell over several columns, I use the `\multicolumn` command. It takes as a first argument the number of columns that should be spanned, as a second the cell types and vertical lines (here, I choose centered and a closing vertical line - the opening vertical line is produced by the first column), and as a third the cell content.
- To introduce a larger vertical spacing between the horizontal lines and the text in the cells, I redefine the `arraystretch` to factor 2.0, by `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.0}`.
- Edit: I included the very good hint of JiyuuSensei: Using `>{\bfseries}` before the column type in the argument of `tabular` typesets all cells in the first column bold-faced, so I don't need to insert that manually in every row.

I hope that helps.

Comment: @Tiuri I was having trouble getting my tables to work as intended yesterday, and I think the `newcolumn` is what I needed. Your answer is both clear and concise, and although I didn't ask the question I also appreciate the answer.

Comment: Deleted my answer as @Tiuri beat me to it :). I do recommend using a column-based text boldness for the first column. You can add `>{\bfseries}` in front of the `C` in `|C{5cm}|` to make all cell contents bold in that column: `|>{\bfseries}C{5cm}|`. Something that really helps when there are many more rows than this. Then you don't need to have `\textbf{}` in every row.