# Confused about arguments given to tabular environment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I'm reading through the not-so-short guide to Latex, and I've just got up to the tabular environment. If I want to create a table with two columns, one  left-aligned and one right-aligned, I write this:

```
\begin{tabular}{lr}
text & more text \\
\end{tabular}
```

Meanwhile, if I wanted the second column to instead have width 1cm and to wrap text, I would write

```
\begin{tabular}{l p{1cm}}
text & more text \\
\end{tabular}
```

My question is this: what if I wanted the second column to be right-aligned *and* to have the behaviour of `p{1cm}`? I see no reason that these commands should be in conflict - the behaviours they cause are completely independent. But I can't see a way of giving both arguments to one column simultaneously.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12703/how-to-create-fixed-width-table-columns-with-text-raggedright-centered-raggedlef/12712#12712

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you! I think I'm happy for this to be closed as a duplicate, then.