# Creating table columns of small fixed width and raggedright/centered/raggedleft?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I read the first answer on this question

[How to create fixed width table columns with text raggedright/centered/raggedleft?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12703/how-to-create-fixed-width-table-columns-with-text-raggedright-centered-raggedlef)

I tried

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{tabular}{|C{0.2cm}|C{0.5cm}|}
\hline
b & c \\
\hline
B & C \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Result is shown below. Why for small sizes we have such an effect? How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.se!  the first column column width is to small for `B` .... try to remove `\hspace{0pt}` from your `C` column definition.

Comment: see answers below. accept one (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer), which help you on the best way :-). by this you will express "thank you" as is here expected (site policy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me elaborate ma comment below question:

- letters `B` as well `b` are wider than 2mm ,what is defined first column width.
- option `\hspace{0pt}` in your `C` column definition prevent cells content to spill-out to next column. consequently `latex` push cells content to next line where this limitation is not in force. consequently you obtain your result.

the possible cures:

- omit`\hspace{0pt}` and by this allow that cell content can use `\tabcolsep` space on the right side of cells and if is necessary spill-out to next column
- increase cells width. for example, if you like to have columns width ratio 2:5, (as can be concluded from your code snippet), than you can define column width as `\begin{tabular}{|C{1em}|C{2.5em}|}`

an example complete small document (called minimal working example: mwe) is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}% for more vertical space in cells
\begin{tabular}{|C{1em}|C{2.5em}|}
    \hline
b & c \\
    \hline
B & C \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

of course you can define other column width, but they should not be small than width of letter `M`, i.e. `1em`.

note: please in future always provide mwe, not just code snippet. with this you will help ust to help you.

Answer (score 0):

why not using ‘tabu’ instead?

An example could be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabu} to 3cm {|X[cm]|X[2cm]|}
    \hline
    b & c \cr
    \hline
    B & C \cr
    \hline
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```