# What is breaking the table?

Tags: tables

From [this answer,](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12712/48787) I have:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{2ex}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{2ex}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{L{0.5in}L{0.5in}Sl}
test & test & test \\
test & test & test \\
test & test & test
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Which gives me my stretched rows and two fixed-width left columns:

[image]

Why fixing the width of the last column breaks it?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{2ex}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{2ex}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{L{0.5in}L{0.5in}L{0.5in}}
test & test & test \\
test & test & test \\
test & test & test
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, the second table misses the `Sl` column

Comment: @egreg Why is it needed? That is what I don't understand. (Or, How do I have all columns fixed-width?)

Comment: Please don't use JPG for non-photographic images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To quote from the [`cellspace` manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/cellspace):

> To improve the spacing of your tables, you must change the table preamble and prepend `S` to the column types `l`,`c`,`r`. The same holds for the paragraph columns `p`, `m`, and `b`, except that they must be surrounded by an extra pair of braces.

The following MWE contains two possibilities that follow this rule either by locally using `S` in the column definition or by including it in a global definition of he new column type `M`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{S{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{2ex}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{2ex}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{S{L{0.5in}}S{L{0.5in}}S{L{0.5in}}}
test & test & test \\
test & test & test \\
test & test & test
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{M{0.5in}M{0.5in}M{0.5in}}
test & test & test \\
test & test & test \\
test & test & test
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```