# How do I create 2 lines and 3 columns in between?

Tags: columns, line

It is my first time to do assignment using LaTeX. My lecturer did not give us the template for this assignment. How do I create a header like this[image] I don't know how to create 2 lines and 3 columns between these two lines.

Comment: Let me guess, creating that header in LaTeX is (part of) the assignment?

Comment: Hi [Kyle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/162596/kyle)! If you found any of the answers useful, please make sure to mark them as accepted (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) how this is done). It helps us out a lot by giving some reputation to both the answerer and yourself as well as it helps others who stumble upon this question. [There is no obligation to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251298/4060736).

Answer (score 2):

For an introduction on creating tables, a good reference is the [tables page on wikibooks.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) Generally speaking, the `booktabs` package handles things like these nicely by introducing `rules`. You can create a table with three columns and two rules by following this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l c r}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textsc{Header}} \\
\toprule
 Text A & Text B & Text C \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

However, to adjust the spacing in your example, I followed [lockstep's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12712/62834) and used the `array` package as well as [Mico's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) suggestions to make the table fit to the page width.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\newlength{\mycolwidth}
\setlength{\mycolwidth}{\tabcolsep}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{L{0.333\textwidth} C{0.333\textwidth} R{0.333\textwidth}}

\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textsc{Department of Mathematics}} \\

\toprule
MATHS 150  & Assignment 3  & Due: 4pm, May 17$^{th}$ 2018 \\
\bottomrule

\end{tabular}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{\mycolwidth}
\end{document}
```

Which produces 
[image: Final Table]

Comment: @Mico thank you for pointing it out! I fixed it

Comment: Thanks again, Mico! I fixed it by setting \tabcolsep to 0pt for this table. While this is certainly not an ideal fix, it is suitable for this purpose. If you have any other suggestion, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

In your case it is probably sufficient to write

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  \hfil\textsc{Department of Mathematics}\hfill\\
  \rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}
  MATHS 150 \hfill Assignment 3  \hfill Due: 4pm, May 17$^{th}$ 2018 \\
  \raisebox{5pt}{\rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}}
\end{document}
```

If it should be indeed a table of some sorts, please refer to Mert's answer. It is not quite clear from your question if you need only this one line (with rules) or a complete tabular structure.