# Horizontal text alignment in a cell in a wide table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have this table in my document, and as you can see the numbers in the second row are not centered, I tried to use some solutions from previously asked questions but none of them fixed this.

[image]

The LaTeX code of this table is:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\parbox{20em}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{cccccc|P{0.02cm}|
        >{\columncolor[HTML]{FD6864}}P{0.02cm} |
        >{\columncolor[HTML]{FD6864}}P{0.02cm} |
        >{\columncolor[HTML]{FD6864}}P{0.02cm} |
        >{\columncolor[HTML]{FD6864}}P{0.02cm} |
        >{\columncolor[HTML]{FD6864}}P{0.02cm} |
        >{\columncolor[HTML]{FD6864}}P{0.02cm} |
        >{\columncolor[HTML]{FD6864}}P{0.02cm} |
        >{\columncolor[HTML]{FD6864}}P{0.02cm} |
        >{\columncolor[HTML]{FD6864}}P{0.02cm} |
        >{\columncolor[HTML]{FD6864}}P{0.02cm} |
        >{\columncolor[HTML]{FD6864}}P{0.02cm} |
        >{\columncolor[HTML]{FD6864}}P{0.02cm} |
        >{\columncolor[HTML]{FD6864}}P{0.02cm} |
        >{\columncolor[HTML]{FD6864}}P{0.02cm} |
        >{\columncolor[HTML]{FD6864}}P{0.02cm} |
        >{\columncolor[HTML]{FD6864}}P{0.02cm} |
        >{\columncolor[HTML]{FD6864}}P{0.02cm} |
        >{\columncolor[HTML]{FD6864}}P{0.02cm} |
        >{\columncolor[HTML]{FD6864}}P{0.02cm} |
        >{\columncolor[HTML]{FD6864}}P{0.02cm} |
        >{\columncolor[HTML]{FD6864}}P{0.02cm} |
        >{\columncolor[HTML]{FD6864}}P{0.02cm} |
        >{\columncolor[HTML]{FD6864}}P{0.02cm} |
        >{\columncolor[HTML]{FD6864}}P{0.02cm} |
        >{\columncolor[HTML]{FD6864}}P{0.02cm} |
        >{\columncolor[HTML]{FD6864}}P{0.02cm} |
        >{\columncolor[HTML]{FD6864}}P{0.02cm} |}
    \cline{7-34}
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                                   & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                            & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                             & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                            & \multicolumn{28}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Something}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}One} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Two} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Three} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Four} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Five} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Six} & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}1 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}2 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}3 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}4 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}5 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}6 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}7 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}8 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}9 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}10 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}11 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}12 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}13 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}14 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}15 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}16 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}17 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}18 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}19 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}20 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}21 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}22 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}23 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}24 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}25 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}26 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}27 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}28 \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{I}                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{-----}                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5}                          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{43}                       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3}                          & 0                                                & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}  &                           &                           &                           &                           &                           &                           &                           &                           &                            &                            &                            &                            &                            &                            & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}   &                            &                            &                            &                            & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}   & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}   &                            &                            &                            &                            &                            & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}   \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{II}                            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0}                              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5}                       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2}                         & 3                                            & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}  & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}  & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}  & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}  & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}  & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}  &                           & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}  & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}  & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}   &                            & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}   & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}   & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}   & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}   & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}   & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}   & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}   & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}   & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}   & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}   & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}   &                            & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}   & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}   & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}   & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}   &                            \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{III}                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0}                                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0}                          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0}                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0}                          & 0                                                & \cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864}  &                           &                           &                           &                           &                           &                           &                           &                           &                            &                            &                            &                            &                            &                            & \cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864}   &                            &                            &                            &                            & \cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864}   & \cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864}   &                            &                            &                            &                            &                            &                            \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{IV}                            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0}                                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0}                          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0}                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0}                          & 0                                                & \cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864}  &                           &                           &                           &                           &                           &                           &                           &                           &                            &                            &                            &                            &                            &                            & \cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864}   &                            &                            &                            &                            & \cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864}   & \cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864}   &                            &                            &                            &                            &                            &                            \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{V}                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0}                                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0}                          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0}                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0}                          & 0                                                & \cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864}  &                           &                           &                           &                           &                           &                           &                           &                           &                            &                            &                            &                            &                            &                            & \cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864}   &                            &                            &                            &                            & \cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864}   & \cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864}   &                            &                            &                            &                            &                            &                            \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Does someone have a solution?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please turn your code fragment into a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that includes the documentclass and all relevant packages that are needed to reproduce the shown output. (How is the `P` type column defined? ...)  Apart from that, you might be interested in [How to create fixed width table columns with text raggedright/centered/raggedleft?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12703/134144)

Comment: Apart from my previous comment, a table with more than 30 columns is most likely a lot wider than the textwidth and will not fit onto yor frame even if you use an extremely small fontsize and tabcolsep.  You might also want to define a custom command instead of using `\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}` and others over and over again. That way it would be easier if you want to change a color later on.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. It looks like you've got two separate accounts.The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: `0.02cm` = `0.2mm` is too small for any readable font to fit. So TeX adds `\tabcolsep` on both sides of this extremely narrow column, also placing the cell contents immediately following the `\tabcolsep`. So, things seem to fit, but it's actually only because of the `\tabcolsep` on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers aren't centered because the columns are too narrow. Below I've used [`collcell`](//ctan.org/pkg/collcell) to collect the cell entries and put them inside a zero-width box. That way they seem to be centered within your `0.2mm` columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  margin=1in,
  landscape
]{geometry}% Just for this example

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{collcell}
\newcommand{\centercell}{\makebox[0pt]}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\collectcell\centercell}m{#1}<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ *{6}{c} | *{28}{>{\columncolor[HTML]{FD6864}}P{0.2mm} |} }
  \cline{7-34}
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 
    \multicolumn{28}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Something}} \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}One} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Two} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Three} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Four} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Five} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Six} & 
  \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}1 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}2 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}3 & 
    \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}4 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}5 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}6 & 
    \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}7 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}8 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}9 & 
    \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}10 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}11 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}12 & 
    \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}13 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}14 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}15 & 
    \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}16 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}17 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}18 & 
    \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}19 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}20 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}21 & 
    \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}22 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}23 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}24 & 
    \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}25 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}26 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}27 & 
    \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}28 \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{I} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{43} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & 0 & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} & 
      & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} & & & & & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} & 
      \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} & & & & & & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{II} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & 3 & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} &
    \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} & 
    \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} & & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} &
    \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} & & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} & 
    \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} & 
    \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} & 
    \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} & 
    \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} & & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} & 
    \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} & \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{III} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} & 0 & \cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864} & 
    & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864} & & & & & \cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864} & 
    \cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864} & & & & & & \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{IV} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} & 0 & \cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864} &
    & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864} & & & & & \cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864} & 
    \cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864} & & & & & & \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{V} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} & 0 & \cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864} & 
    & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864} & & & & & \cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864} & 
    \cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864} & & & & & & \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Note the code simplification for defining multiple columns with the same specification: `*{<num>}{<col spec>}`. Not only does it simplify the input, but it makes it more maintainable.