# Design a complex structure table in latex

Tags: tables

I am new in latex. Thus, I can design basic table, not this complex one given below(this one designed in MS Word): 
[image]

Please help me how to design the above table. Don't worry about the text. I just need the design.

Comment: Please extend your code to a [complete but minimal compilable document](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) such that it's easier for others to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for `\multicolumn` and `\multirow`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{2.3cm}}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12712/156344
\begin{document}
\setcounter{table}{11}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Some caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|C|C|C|C|C|C|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Long long long long long long long long text} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Long long long long long long long long text}\\
        \hline 
        Text & Primary Code & Text & Text & Text & Text\\
        \hline
        Text & Text & \multirow[t]{2}{*}{Some text} & Text & Text & \multirow[t]{2}{*}{Some text}\\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5}
        Text & Text & & Text & Text & \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The additional horizontal rules will mess up your table, so I removed it, and *please don't use it*.

And here is the recommended version, with all vertical lines removed and some changes in the thickness of horizontal lines (with the help of `booktabs`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{2.3cm}}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{table}{11}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Some caption}
    \begin{tabular}{CCCCCC}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Long long long long long long long long text} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Long long long long long long long long text}\\
        \midrule
        Text & Primary Code & Text & Text & Text & Text\\
        %\midrule
        \cmidrule(r){1-3} \cmidrule(l){4-6} % For better column separation, thanks to Mico!
        Text & Text & \multirow[t]{2}{*}{Some text} & Text & Text & \multirow[t]{2}{*}{Some text}\\
        Text & Text & & Text & Text & \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Do consider replacing the first `\midrule` with `\cmidrule(r){1-3} \cmidrule(l){4-6}`.

Comment: @Mico Oh, thanks! I did not think of that. Btw, I think we should replace the second `\midrule` instead of the first.

Comment: I think it's preferable to provide more visual structure to the header rows. Otherwise, it's not obvious whether "Some text" pertains just to "Primary Code" or to all three subheaders.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the feedback. Added :)

Comment: @JouleV Thanks for the help.  I just tried your design with my data, it works fine. However, the table size breaks the page margin. How to limit the table within page margin. Please see the image here:  https://imgur.com/ggav0Re

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you employ a `tabularx` environment, overall width set to `\textwidth`, with 6 equal-width columns. I also suggest you omit all vertical lines and employ fewer, but well-spaced horizontal lines (using the macros of the `booktabs` package), to give the table a more open "look".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % select a suitable document class
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set suitable page parameters
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % optional
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e,amsmath}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ED}{ED}
\newcommand\ris{\mathrm{ris}}
\newcommand\rs{\mathrm{rs}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\caption{Example comparison of \dots\ between previous and our approaches}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} *{6}{C} @{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{`\dots' coded `ri' (Previous Approach)} &
\multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{`\dots' coded `r' (Our Approach)} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-3} \cmidrule(l){4-6}
Word & Primary Word & Edit Distance & Word & Primary Word & Edit Distance \\
\midrule
\dots\ (correct)   & Ris & $\ED(\ris\mid \rs)=1$ & & & \\ \addlinespace
\dots\ (incorrect) & Rs  &                       & & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to construct that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (however, as many people, I recommend a design in the spirit of `booktabs`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{table}{11}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Some caption}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{*{6}{m[c]{2.3cm}}}[hvlines]
        \Block{1-3}{Long long long long long long long long text} &&&
              \Block{1-3}{Long long long long long long long long text} \\
        Text & Primary Code & Text & Text & Text & Text\\
        Text & Text & \Block{2-1}{} Some text & Text & Text & \Block{2-1}{} Some text \\ 
        Text & Text & & Text & Text & \\ 
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]