# Extra alignment tab while using multirow

Tags: tables, multirow

Why the following multirow entry doesn't work with `tabular`?

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\title{my title} 
\maketitle
\section{Section 1}
Table~\ref{my-label} shows 
  \begin{table} 
  \centering    
  \caption{the caption}
  \label{my-label}
  \begin{tabular}{>{\centering}p{1.5cm}|>{\centering}p{1.5cm} }
        \multirow{2}{*}{some texts}  & something1 \\
                                     & something2 \\
        \tabularnewline
        \hline
         A & B 
        \tabularnewline

  \end{tabular}
  \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

The error is

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate 

l.81                                     &
                                      something2 \\
?
```

Comment: This  code can't work, but, loading `multirow` and `array`, it compiles fine.

Comment: Use `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}` instead of `>{\centering}p{1.5cm}`  see the possible duplicate [How to create fixed width table columns with text raggedright/centered/raggedleft?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12703/134144) for more explanation