# How to set the width of the last column with tabular package?

Tags: tables, columns, width, csvsimple

I want to generate a table with fixed column width. This works for all the columns except for the last column.

Working example (fixed column width for all column except the last one)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{grade.csv}
    name,givennamex,matriculation,gender,grade
    Maier,Hans,12348,m,1.0
    Huber,Anna,23456,f,2.3
    Weisbaeck,Werner,34567,m,5.0
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}m{2cm}|>{\raggedright}m{2cm}|c}%
        \bfseries long title column 1 & \bfseries long title column 2 & \bfseries long title column 3% specify table head
        \csvreader[head to column names]{grade.csv}{}% use head of csv as column names
        {\\\hline\givennamex & \name & \matriculation}% specify your columns here
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Example with problem (fixed column width for all column including the last one)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{grade.csv}
    name,givennamex,matriculation,gender,grade
    Maier,Hans,12348,m,1.0
    Huber,Anna,23456,f,2.3
    Weisbaeck,Werner,34567,m,5.0
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}m{2cm}|>{\raggedright}m{2cm}|>{\raggedright}m{2cm}}%
        \bfseries long title column 1 & \bfseries long title column 2 & \bfseries long title column 3% specify table head
        \csvreader[head to column names]{grade.csv}{}% use head of csv as column names
        {\\\hline\givennamex & \name & \matriculation}% specify your columns here
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

What can I do to set the width of the last column?

**EDIT**

After the comments below I added the package `ragged2e` and changed the first line

```
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}m{2cm}|>{\raggedright}m{2cm}|>{\raggedright}m{2cm}}%
```

to this one

```
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}m{2cm}|>{\raggedright}m{2cm}|m{2cm}}%
```

Overall, the code is now the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{filecontents*}{grade.csv}
    name,givennamex,matriculation,gender,grade
    Maier,Hans,12348,m,1.0
    Huber,Anna,23456,f,2.3
    Weisbaeck,Werner,34567,m,5.0
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}m{2cm}|>{\raggedright}m{2cm}|m{2cm}}%
        \bfseries long title column 1 & \bfseries long title column 2 & \bfseries long title column 3% specify table head
        \csvreader[head to column names]{grade.csv}{}% use head of csv as column names
        {\\\hline\givennamex & \name & \matriculation}% specify your columns here
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

There is still one Problem: I cannot set the last column as centered (I tried to write `>{\raggedright}m{2cm}` instead of `m{2cm}` but it doesn't work).

Comment: use `>{\raggedright \arraybackslash}` in the last column, or use `\tabularnewline` instead of `\\ ` to terminate the lines.

Comment: Related:[How to create fixed width table columns with text raggedright/centered/raggedleft?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12703/134144)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize [the comment by Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498563/how-to-set-the-width-of-the-last-column-with-tabular-package/498709#comment1259175_498563): here are three possibilites:

1. Use `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}` instad of `>{\raggedright}`.
2. Define your own column type with `\newcolumntype` to avoid repeaded typing of the cde meintioned in 1.
3. Use `\tabularnewline` instead of `\\` to end a line in the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{filecontents*}{grade.csv}
    name,givennamex,matriculation,gender,grade
    Maier,Hans,12348,m,1.0
    Huber,Anna,23456,f,2.3
    Weisbaeck,Werner,34567,m,5.0
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2cm}}%
        \bfseries long title column 1 & \bfseries long title column 2 & \bfseries long title column 3% specify table head
        \csvreader[head to column names]{grade.csv}{}% use head of csv as column names
        {\\\hline\givennamex & \name & \matriculation}% specify your columns here
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{R{2cm}|R{2cm}|R{2cm}}%
        \bfseries long title column 1 & \bfseries long title column 2 & \bfseries long title column 3% specify table head
        \csvreader[head to column names]{grade.csv}{}% use head of csv as column names
        {\\\hline\givennamex & \name & \matriculation}% specify your columns here
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}m{2cm}|>{\raggedright}m{2cm}| >{\raggedright}m{2cm}}%
        \bfseries long title column 1 & \bfseries long title column 2 & \bfseries long title column 3% specify table head
        \csvreader[head to column names]{grade.csv}{}% use head of csv as column names
        {\tabularnewline\hline\givennamex & \name & \matriculation}% specify your columns here
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: many thanks for your answer @leandriis. However, how can I do so the last column ist then centered and not align on the right / left (cf. last comment in the question)

Comment: To horizontally center the last column replace `\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2cm}}` in the first table by `\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}}`

Comment: Many Thanks @leandriis. That solved the problem