# Force line break on `\citep{}` inside `longtable` (XeLaTeX)

Tags: tables, xetex, citing, line-breaking

I am trying to create a quite long table that will also contain citations inside, but the `\breakcites` macro apparently does not work inside `tabular` environment. Placing `\citep` inside `\makecell` does not work, either.

Here is MWE: (I am using XeLaTeX)

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in, top=1.88in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.25in, right=1.13in]{geometry}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\pagestyle{plain}
%\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex} 

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\doublespacing
\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ll}
\caption{Summary of relevant computational parameters from various computational studies. This table is modified from \cite{Rojas}.}
\hline
Computational parameter            & Utilized parameter \\ 
\hline
Program                            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\makecell{Spanish Initiative for Electronic Simulation with \\ Thousands of Atoms (SIESTA) \citep{lopezcorral,Sigal}} \\  \\ Vienna Ab-Inito Simulation Package (VASP) \\ \citep{Gurel,Rojas,ZhouMiao,Li2015,ChiChen} \\ Gaussian 09 \\ \citep{Gholami2016,Rad} \\ Quantum Espresso \\ \citep{Khodadadi,Wong} \\ DMol3 \citep{Jungsuttiwong} \end{tabular}                     \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

I used a separate bib file for the references. Here is screenshot of what happens when I compile the code above:

[image]

Is there a way to force line breaks at the `\citep`?

Note: I know the `tabular` inside `tabular` is not the optimal way to do stuff but I did not change it to another form since the output looks nice, and I don't think it has something to do with the problem. I have tried a cleaner code but the same problem arises.

Comment: AFAICS this is not specific to `\citep` it would happen with every other text as well. `l` columns in tables never automatically break lines, instead they expand to the natural width of their content. You could use `p` columns (but would need to give a fixed length, i.e. `p{2cm}` instead of just `l`). But that would give you justified text, which you may not like, in which case you may be interested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12703/35864. If you don't want to give the column width manually, you may want to look at `tabularx`'s `X` columns.

Comment: @moewe the solution at the link worked! would you like to post this as separate answer?

Comment: Do you want me to type up an answer or would you also be OK with marking this question as a duplicate?

Comment: I am okay with marking this as duplicate to direct them to the link you shared a while ago.