# I need these two boxes to be the same length using tabular

Tags: tabularx, width

The box on the left should mirror the box on the right. So A should look as if it's spanning 3 columns and 2 rows, etc. How can I fix the width of the table on the right using tabular? Code is below. Sorry in advance - I am very new at this. 
[image: What it currently looks like]

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|ccc|c|}
\hline
2 & 1 & 4 & 10 \\
0 & 5 & -1 & 6 \\
\hline
3 & 7 & -8 & 9 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
=
\begin{tabular}{|ccc|c|}
\hline
&\multirow{2}{*}{$A$}&&\multirow{2}{*}{$\hat{b}$} \\
&&& \\ \hline
&$\bar{c}$&&$d$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The width of each column in a `tabular` environment can be specified in the argument at the beginning of the environment. The letters `l`, `c` and `r` are used to declare left aligned, centered and right aligned columns respectively, but one can also use the letter `p`, which takes a length as an argument to specify the width of the column. With the `array` package, one can also use the similar commands `m` and `b`. The difference between `p`, `m` and `b` is the vertical alignment of the text; use `p` to align at the top of the cell, `m` in the middle and `b` at the bottom. See the [LaTeX wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#The_tabular_environment) for a more detailed explanation. The answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12703/how-to-create-fixed-width-table-columns-with-text-raggedright-centered-raggedlef) can also be useful, as it introduces a way to define horizontally centered columns with specified width.

Taking your example, the `c` arguments can be replaced by `m`s to give the following result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol, multirow, array}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|m{2ex}m{2ex}m{2ex}|m{2ex}|}
\hline
2 & 1 & 4 & 10 \\
0 & 5 & -1 & 6 \\
\hline
3 & 7 & -8 & 9 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
=
\begin{tabular}{|m{2ex}m{2ex}m{2ex}|m{2ex}|}
\hline
&\multirow{2}{*}{$A$}&&\multirow{2}{*}{$\hat{b}$} \\
&&& \\ \hline
&$\bar{c}$&&$d$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you are so amazing!!!!! thank you

Comment: I am getting an "Undefined control sequence" error now when I add this code to my document. "Undefined control sequence.
\adl@hline ...mpcnta \xdef \adl@rowsL {\adl@rowsL 
                                                  (#1/\number \@tempcnta );}...
l.123 \hline"

Comment: Did you load the ``multirow`` and the ``array`` packages?

Comment: I did! I was told erasing the aux file might help. When I put the code in a new tex file it works just fine

Answer (score 1):

You can also measure the width and height.  It will save some space, but obviously takes more effort.

Note that even a [b] tabular will still have a nonzero depth.  Also, in the `\parbox`, the first [c] centers `b`, while the second [c] centers `A`.  The `\strut` improves the centering.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol, multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\sbox0{\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
2 & 1 & 4 \\
0 & 5 & -1 \\
3 & 7 & -8
\end{tabular}}% measure width \wd0
\sbox1{\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
2 & 1 & 4 \\
0 & 5 & -1
\end{tabular}}% measure height \ht1 + \dp1
\begin{tabular}{|ccc|c|}
\hline
2 & 1 & 4 & 10 \\
0 & 5 & -1 & 6 \\
\hline
3 & 7 & -8 & 9 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
=
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\parbox[c][\dimexpr \ht1+\dp1][c]{\wd0}{\centering \strut $A$} & $\hat{b}$ \\
\hline
$\bar{c}$&$d$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you SO much!!

Comment: I also get an error with this one. Undefined control sequence.

Comment: I get no errors or warnings.  Try erasing the aux file (clear project).

Comment: I don't get warning when I put it in a new tex file. I'm still getting the error even after erasing the aux file :(

Comment: I actually fixed this by moving the {multicol, multirow} to the top of my list? weird!