# Error: Table too wide

Tags: tables

I'm writing some notes to my class and I create a table but is too wide and it cannot be compiled in my document. Could you help me with my code? I think I need to modify the rows because some part of the contents are too long and that creates the error but I'm really beginner using Tables.
Thanks to anyone.

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l|c|l|r}
    &\textbf{Parámetro} & \textbf{Definición} & \textbf{Intensidad}\\\hline\hline
    1&Especialización & El puesto ejecuta un número reducido de tareas diferentes & Muy alta\\
    2&Formalización de comportamiento & Puesto con tareas simples diseñadas por personas diferentes al ejecutor & Muy alta\\
    3&Entrenamiento & Práctica de un trabajo por un largo tiempo, fuera del trabajo y solitariamente & Muy baja\\
    4&Adoctrinamiento & Conjunto de valores, objetivos o cultura común & Muy baja\\
    5&Planificación y control & Planificación: Definición de tareas antes de la ejecución. Control: Monitoreo de las tareas después de la ejecución & Muy alta\\
    6&Comunicación informal & Coordinación fuera del plan & Muy baja\\
    7&Centralización & El poder pertenece en la parte alta de la estrategia & Relativamente alta
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Tipos de alineamiento}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

Comment: The best way to make a table with extensive text in its cells narrower is to format the text as (ragged right) paragraphs.  This question shows how to do that: [How to create fixed width table columns with text raggedright/centered/raggedleft?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12703)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}

\noindent% <-- important
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l|Z|X|l}
        &\textbf{Parámetro} & \textbf{Definición} & \textbf{Intensidad}\\\hline\hline
        1&Especialización & El puesto ejecuta un número reducido de tareas diferentes & Muy alta\\
        2&Formalización de comportamiento & Puesto con tareas simples diseñadas por personas diferentes al ejecutor & Muy alta\\
        3&Entrenamiento & Práctica de un trabajo por un largo tiempo, fuera del trabajo y solitariamente & Muy baja\\
        4&Adoctrinamiento & Conjunto de valores, objetivos o cultura común & Muy baja\\
        5&Planificación y control & Planificación: Definición de tareas antes de la ejecución. Control: Monitoreo de las tareas después de la ejecución & Muy alta\\
        6&Comunicación informal & Coordinación fuera del plan & Muy baja\\
        7&Centralización & El poder pertenece en la parte alta de la estrategia & Relativamente alta
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Tipos de alineamiento}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

Comment: What's the “important” `\noindent` for? The `\setlength` declaration should go *inside* the `table` environment, so it is local to the table.