# Table with multicolumn highlighted row

Tags: multicolumn, rowcolor, cellcolor

I'm trying to make the following table:

[image]

I can create the structure easily. However I have a problem in the row colour:

```
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}} % table type

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Summary} 
\label{tab:Summary}
\makebox[\textwidth]{ %to center the table if exceed page width
    \begin{tabular}{L{1cm} L{4cm}  L{4cm}  L{4cm}}
        %Title
        \hline \rowcolor{black}
        \multicolumn{4}{L{13cm}}{\textcolor{white}{Title goes here}} \TBstrut \\ 
        \hline \rowcolor{black}
        %
        \textcolor{white}{id}           & 
        \textcolor{white}{Description}  & 
        \textcolor{white}{Formula}      & 
        \textcolor{white}{Notes} \TBstrut \\ \hline 
        %
        text & text  & $equation$  & Text \TBstrut \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

I get the following:

[image]

I also tried replacing it with the following but I get the same result

```
\multicolumn{4}{L{13cm}}{\cellcolor{black}\textcolor{white}{Title goes here}} \TBstrut \\
```

I assume that this is due the missing margins (left/right) from the border for each cell. Any idea how to fix?

Note that the cell type is from: [How to create fixed width table columns with text raggedright/centered/raggedleft?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12703/how-to-create-fixed-width-table-columns-with-text-raggedright-centered-raggedlef)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What happens if you change `\multicolumn{4}{L{13cm}}{...}` to ``\multicolumn{4}{l}{...}``?

Comment: @Mico That was a simple solution! Cheers :)

Comment: would you like to upvote the answer if it was helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Summary} 
\label{tab:Summary}
    \begin{tabular}{m{1cm} m{4cm}  m{4cm}  m{4cm}}
        %Title
        \hline \rowcolor{black}
        \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textcolor{white}{Title goes here}}  \\ 
        \hline \rowcolor{black}
        %
        \textcolor{white}{id}           & 
        \textcolor{white}{Description}  & 
        \textcolor{white}{Formula}      & 
        \textcolor{white}{Notes}  \\ \hline 
        %
        text & text  & $equation$  & Text  \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes replacing with the original (l) (c) fixes it. :)