# Table's width getting out of page

Tags: tables, width

I got this problem with overfull and I don't really know how to arrange the width of my table.

[image]

[image]

I also want to put the Celsius symbol in a new line (just under the Temperature in the same cell)

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12712/202560 ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! See the `makecell` package and its eponymous command for line breaks in standard cells.

Comment: (1) Rewrite your headers to be much shorter (2) use table notes to provide the long headers, (3) never ever just post an image of the code. Do you really expect others to want to retype the code by hand to test it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you employ a `tabularx` environment and allow automatic line-breakins in all header cells.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\caption{Choice of test conditions}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} CCCCC @{}}
\toprule
Set of Conditions & 
Temperature [\si{\celsius}] & 
Desired RH differential [\%] & 
RH of upper chamber [\%] & 
RH of lower chamber [\%]\\
\midrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```