# Problem in table with fixed width columns and multicolumn

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I want to do a diagram following the idea of [How to create fixed width table columns with text raggedright/centered/raggedleft?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12703/how-to-create-fixed-width-table-columns-with-text-raggedright-centered-raggedlef). Using the code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| C{2cm} | C{2cm} | C{2cm} | C{2cm} | C{2cm} | C{2cm} |}
\hline
$f(x)$   & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{+}\\
\hline
$f'(x)$  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{+} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{-} & +\\
\hline
$f''(x)$ & - & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{-} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{+}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

the widths are ignored:

[image: bad widths]

But adding a multicolumn-less row:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{| C{2cm} | C{2cm} | C{2cm} | C{2cm} | C{2cm} | C{2cm} |}
\hline
$f(x)$   & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{+}\\
\hline
$f'(x)$  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{+} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{-} & +\\
\hline
$f''(x)$ & + & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{-} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{+}\\
\hline
U & V & W & X & Y & Z\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

the widths are OK:

[image: good widths]

What I'm missing?

Comment: your C column specifcations are not used at all after the first column as you are removing them all, specifiying alternative column specifications with multicolumn

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, yes, but... using "C" instead "c" gives a lot of "Illegal unit of measure" errors.

Comment: Obviously you can't use `C` on its own as you have defined it to take an argument, but `C{\dimexpr4cm+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}` would make a column the width of a two column span

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you use (a) an `array` environment rather than a `tabular` environment (since the table's contents are all in math mode) and (b) use the `w` column type to specify the column widths as no line-breaking within columns would seem necessary or desirable. Since the tedious-looking

```
\multicolumn{2}{w{c}{\dimexpr2\mylen+2\arraycolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}
```

expression occurs no fewer four times, I further suggest replacing it with a shortcut macro called, say, `\mycol`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}  % for 'w' column type
\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{1cm} % <-- set the desired usable column width (2cm seems excessive)
% handy shortcut macro:
\newcommand\mycol[1]{%
   \multicolumn{2}{w{c}{\dimexpr2\mylen+2\arraycolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}{#1}} 
\begin{document}
\[ % start an unnumbered display-math group
\begin{array}{| *{6}{w{c}{\mylen}|} }
\hline
f(x)   & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{+}    \\
\hline
f'(x)  & \mycol{+} & \mycol{-} & + \\
\hline
f''(x) & - & \mycol{-} & \mycol{+} \\
\hline
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily construct that array with `{NiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`. That environment is similar to `{nicematrix}` (of `amsmath`) but with additionnal features:

- You can specify the width of the columns with the key `columns-width`.
- You can merge cells (both vertically and horizontally) with the command `\Block`.
- The key `hvlines` draws all the rules (except in the blocks created by `\Block`).

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{NiceMatrix}[columns-width=1cm,hvlines]
f(x)   & \Block{1-5}{+} \\
f'(x)  & \Block{1-2}{+} && \Block{1-2}{+} && + \\
f''(x) & - & \Block{1-2}{-} && \Block{1-2}{+} \\
\end{NiceMatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]