# Table, new line and centering problem

Tags: tables, align, line-breaking

I want to create a table where in each column I need to write something in two (or more than) lines. I also want that in each cell all the entries will be aligned at the centre.

I tried one code as follows. It serves the "two or more line" condition. But I am unable to make the alignment at centre. Any help?

Code:

```
\begin{table}[h]
    
    \centering \def\arraystretch{1.5} \small
    
    \begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|}
        
        \hline
        
        quantum electrodynamics & hello \par left & aligned \par efgh \\ \hline
        
        electromagnetism & hello \par left & aligned \par efgh \\ \hline
        
        classical physics & hello \par world & abcd \par efgh \\ \hline
        
    \end{tabular}
    
\end{table}
```

The output is:

[image]

Comment: use the `makecell` package for multiline text

Comment: @jsbibra Thanks. Could you please refer to any link or anything that can help to create the table in your way?

Comment: welcome to the site -- please have   alook at the answer below with the versatile `nicematrix` package -- verticals are normally not used in tables avoids the jailed look -- if you require go ahead -- `booktabs` package gives nice spaced horizontal rules -- the `Y` type column gives the `centered` text -- the `0.4` and `0.6` give the percentage of `textwidth` to be occupied - in case of difficulty please revert

Comment: The answers to [How to create fixed width table columns with text raggedright/centered/raggedleft?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12703/134144) might also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{booktabs}


\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1\textwidth}}
\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{Y{0.4}Y{0.6}}
    \toprule[2pt]
    Vantagens & Desvantagens \\ 
    \midrule 
    Rede mais simples & Difícil correcção e detecção de erros \\ 
    \midrule
    Implementação mais barata & Uma quebra no cabo pode comprometer o acesso dos dispositivos à rede \\ 
    \midrule
    Não são necessários equipamento complexos & Problemático ao adicionar e remover dispositivos da rede  \\ 
    \bottomrule[2pt]
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

In case only left aligned text is required use

```
   \begin{NiceTabular}{p{0.4\textwidth}p{0.6\textwidth}}
```

in place of the Y type column

Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It will help.

Comment: For the record: The newly defined `Y` type column can also be used inside of a regular `tabular`, it doe not depend on the use of the `nicematrix` package.

Comment: The table currently exceeds the textwidth, you might want to fix that.