# Table alignment of text left with tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx, alignment

Currently, I am using tabularx what enables me to set columnwidth. The only thing that I would like to change is to align all text on the left side, instead of how it is now (centered in some cases). For example: "primary functional goals" is in a centered (?) way aligned, instead of on the left side, what I prefer. In the images you see my code and the result.

Thank you!

[image: Code and result of the table]

Comment: edit your question and copy paste your code here so that it can be compiled by others -- else everything will have to be typed in once again

Comment: See also: [How to create fixed width table columns with text raggedright/centered/raggedleft?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12703/134144)