# Left alignment of text in table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

how do I left align this table? I do not want to justify it.

```
    \centering
    \caption{Characteristics and classification of hydrological model}
    \begin{tabular}{ p{4.9cm} p{4.9cm} p{4.9cm} }
     \hline
     Empirical model & Conceptual model & Physically based model \\
     \hline
     Data based or metric or black box model & 
     Parametric or grey box model &
     Mechanistic or white box model \\
     \hline
     Involve mathematical equations, Derive value from available time series &
     Based on modeling of reservoirs, Include semi empirical equations with a physical basis &
     Based on spatial distribution, Evaluation of parameters describing physical characteristics \\
     \hline
     Little consideration of features and processes of system &
     Parameters are derived from field data and calibration &
     Require data about initial state of model and morphology of catchment \\
     \hline
     High predictive power, low explanatory depth &
     Simple and can be easily implemented in computer code &
     Complex model. Require human expertise and computation capability \\
     \hline
     ANN, Unit hydrograph &
     HBV model, TOPMODEL &
     SHE or MIKESHE model, SWAT \\
     \hline
     \end{tabular}
    \source{Gayathri K Devii et al. (2015) \cite{CITE26}}
    \label{tab:table2}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Try `\begin{tabular}{ *{3}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4.9cm} } }`. If you will extend your code snippet to complete small document (MWE: Minimal working Example) beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, I can provide complete answer.

Comment: See also: [How to create fixed width table columns with text raggedright/centered/raggedleft?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12703/134144)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you (a) switch from a `tabular` to a `tabularx` environment and set the width of the `tabularx` environment to `\textwidth`, (b) use `\RaggedRight` in all 3 columns, and (c) use fewer but well-spaced horizontal rules.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\providecommand{\source}[1]{{\footnotesize\raggedright Source: #1\par}} % ??
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Characteristics and classification of hydrological model\strut}
\label{tab:table2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ @{} LLL @{} }
     \toprule
     Empirical model & Conceptual model & Physically based model \\
     \midrule
     Data based or metric or black box model & 
     Parametric or grey box model &
     Mechanistic or white box model \\
     \addlinespace
     Involve mathematical equations, derive value from available time series &
     Based on modeling of reservoirs, include semi empirical equations with a physical basis &
     Based on spatial distribution, evaluation of parameters describing physical characteristics \\
     \addlinespace
     Little consideration of features and processes of system &
     Parameters are derived from field data and calibration &
     Require data about initial state of model and morphology of catchment \\
     \addlinespace
     High predictive power, low explanatory depth &
     Simple and can be easily implemented in computer code &
     Complex model. Require human expertise and computation capability\\
     \addlinespace
     ANN, Unit hydrograph &
     HBV model, TOPMODEL &
     SHE or MIKESHE model, SWAT \\
     \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\smallskip
\source{Gayathri K. Devii et~al.\ (2015) \cite{CITE26}}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```