# Text in longtable uses too large spacing

Tags: tables, longtable, line-spacing

### Description

I'm using a longtable in my LaTeX document and I limit each section of the table with `p{...cm}`. This leads to automatic line breaks in the text which is what I want. My problem is that in these lines some of the spacing between the words is just too large instead of a single space. I would like a single space inbetween.

### Example Code

```
\begin{longtable}[h!] {|p{3.5cm}|p{3.25cm}|p{6.5cm}|p{2cm}|}
...
    \hline
Konfiguration & Änderung der Konfiguration während der Laufzeit & Die Konfiguration MUSS zur Laufzeit der Komponenten veränderbar sein. & MUSS \\ 
    \hline
...
\end{longtable}
```

### Example Screenshot

[image: Screenshot of the result of the code above]

As u can see in the second column there are very large spaces beetween "Änderung der" and "während der".  How do I get rid of this and only use single spaces between?

Comment: you are justifying text in narrow columns. Hopefully you have enabled German hyphenation but better use ragged setting `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.5cm}}` (requires `array` package)

Comment: You need to use `\Raggedright` (requires the package `ragged2e`).  The answers to this question might help: [How to create fixed width table columns with text raggedright/centered/raggedleft?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12703)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you very much this worked!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried your method but unfortunately reloading and interpreting somehow didn't finish.

Comment: you did something wrong then but can not guess what but no matter: now you have something working we can close as duplicate

Comment: `\begin{longtable}[h!]`  longtable has no `h` or `!` options. Whatever the intention there it is doing nothing useful.