# Fit a large table into a page without \resizebox

Tags: tables

I am trying to fit the following table into a page but `\resizebox` is changing the font size and is making it too small compared to the rest of the document.

Here is the code I am using with `\resizebox`:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{llcl}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Region}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Inferred by experiment\end{tabular}}}                                         & Protein1                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c} protein2                            \\ \midrule
        &                                                                                                                                       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Structure at T0}}                                                                                                                               \\ \cline{3-4}
        &                                                                                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}F74, T75, E76, D77, M79, \textbf{\textcolor{red}{V80}}, P81, \textbf{\textcolor{red}{G83}}, L84, \\ T86, G87, Q88, A90, L91\end{tabular}}}                                                                                                                                                                   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}V6, P7, G10, L11, L13, V14, L17, G18,\\ F20, M21, Y24 V26, R27, M79,\textbf{\textcolor{red}{V80}},\\ L82, \textbf{\textcolor{red}{G83}}, L84, Y85, T86, G87, A90  \end{tabular}                                                                        \\ \cline{3-4}
        &                                                                                                                                       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Equilibrated structures}}                                                                                                                                               \\ \cline{3-4}
        \multirow{-10}{*}{Protein interface}   & \multirow{-10}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}V80, G83, Q88, N92,\\ W93, W95, I98,\\ F100, G101, A102,\\ D111, V118\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}M1, P2, S4, W5, P7, A8, G10, L11, T12,L13, V14, \\ P15, L17, G18, M21, G22, F25,V26, E29, Y34, \\ L37, K39, P40, R46, V67,W68, E70, L71, D77, \\ A78, M79, \textbf{\textcolor{red}{V80}}, P81,L82, \textbf{\textcolor{red}{G83}}, Y85, T86, G87, \end{tabular}} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}S4, V6, P7, V9, G10, L11, T12, L13, V14,\\ P15, L17, G18, F20, M21, G22, Y24,\\ F25, V26, R27, G28, E29, G30, L31, R32  \end{tabular} 
        \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
}
\caption{Table} \end{table}
```

Here is what the table looks like:

[image]

I also tried using `\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}`, but it did not give the desired output. Any other suggestions? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE! Please provide complete small  document with your table. We need to know your page layout.

Comment: You could just reduce the width of the columns, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12712/123129).

Comment: Unrelated: Don't use `\cline` when you're already using the `booktabs` rules. Use `\cmidrule` instead, then you get better space around those lines.

Comment: You might want to change "lare" in the title to "large".

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

- you not provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document with your table. Consequently your page layout is unknown.
- To demonstrate, how you can set table, I use `article` documentclass and determine page layout with `geometry` package.
- you can determine table width for example with `tabular*`, `xtabular`, `tabularray` packages ...
- In MWE below is used `tabularray` package.
- It is not entirely clear how should table looks, so in MWE is just guessing that you may you liked showed table design.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\newcommand\bfc[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \caption{Table}
    \label{tab:?}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={@{} X[0.3,l] X[0.7, l] X[j] X[j] @{}},
             row{1}={font=\bfseries,c,m}
             }
    \toprule
Region  &   Inferred by experiment  
            & Protein 1     
                &   Protein 2   \\ 
    \midrule
\SetCell[r=4]{l} Protein interface
        &   \SetCell[r=4]{l}    V80, G83, Q88, N92,
                                W93, W95, I98,
                                F100, G101, A102,
                                D111, V118
            &   \SetCell[c=2]{c, font=\bfseries}    Structure at T0
                &               \\ 
    \midrule
        &   &   F74, T75, E76, D77, M79, \bfc{V80}, P81,
                \bfc{G83}, L84, T86, G87, Q88, A90, L91                                                                                                                                                                 &   V6, P7, G10, L11, L13, V14, L17, G18,
                    F20, M21, Y24 V26, R27, M79, \bfc{V80},
                    L82, \bfc{G83}, L84, Y85, T86, G87, A90
                                \\ 
    \midrule[dashed]
       &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c, font=\bfseries} Equilibrated 
                &               \\ 
    \midrule
        &   &   M1, P2, S4, W5, P7, A8, G10, L11, T12,L13, V14,
                P15, L17, G18, M21, G22, F25,V26, E29, Y34,
                37, K39, P40, R46, V67,W68, E70, L71, D77,
                A78, M79, \bfc{V80}, P81,L82, \bfc{G83}, Y85, T86, G87,
                &   S4, V6, P7, V9, G10, L11, T12, L13, V14,
                    P15, L17, G18, F20, M21, G22, Y24,
                    F25, V26, R27, G28, E29, G30, L31, R32
                                \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @FZJ, you are welcome. If answer solve your problem, you may consider to accept it (by clicking on the check mark attop left side of the answer).