# how to set right align of "p{}" in table

Tags: tables, align, longtable

I want to have a list of texts in a document, and I use the "longtable" package to make the list.
The codes as as following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}[h]{|p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0.60\textwidth}|p{0.2\textwidth}|}
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{texts}}\\
        text 1-1                            &text 1-2                     &text 1-3    \\
        text 2-1                            &text 2-2                     &text 2-3    \\
        text 3-1                            &text 3-2                     &text 3-3    \\
        text 4-1                            &text 4-2                     &text 4-3    \\
        text 5-1                            &text 5-2                     &text 5-3    \\
        text 6-1                            &text 6-2                     &text 6-3    \\
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The document is as following.

[image]

The texts are left aligned by default.

The question is, I want to set the first and second column as "left align" and the thrid column as "right align".
While, it seems that I can not use `{llr}` and `{|p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0.60\textwidth}|p{0.2\textwidth}|}` at the same time.

Then, how could I set the the width of column and set the align?

Comment: Try `>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}` before the `p{…}` you want right aligned. See the manual of package `array` for more information.

Comment: If you don't need automatic line breaks, you could use `w{r}{0.2\textwidth}` from the `array` package

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12703/277964

Comment: Off-topic: Your `longtable` is to wide, because `0.2\textwidth` + `0.6\textwidth` + `0.2\textwidth` + `6\tabcolsep` (two for each column) are already > `\textwidth`. You either should reduce the width of at least one column or maybe you want to use package `xltabular` or `tabularray` to avoid such issues. And please note, that environment `longtable` does not support option `[h]` only `[c]`, `[l]` and `[r]` are supported. See Table 7 in the `longtable` manual for more information.

Comment: In the above example, all of the texts are one line, in which case you should be using l, c, and r columns.  You can preset the width using \makebox or the makecell package.