# Please help me to run this code in LateX!

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, columns

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| >{\centering}p{2.5cm}  | >{\centering}p{0.5cm}  | >{\centering}p{2.5cm} |>{\centering}p{2.5cm} |>{\centering}p{2.5cm} |>{\centering}p{2.5cm} |}
\hline
Abc & Bcd & A long cell with text that wraps around and is centered & long cell with text  & AAAlong cell with text that wraps around and is centered & SSSlong cell with text that wraps around and is centered \\
1 & 3 & qw & qe & sad &11\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If the centering is your only problem, then the question is a duplicate of [Center column with specifying width in table (tabular enviroment)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/center-column-with-specifying-width-in-table-tabular-enviroment).

Comment: @Strong: Welcome to tex.sx! +1 for your working minimal example. Would you mind to change your question title to something more descriptive (e.g. "Using `\centering` inside table column definition results in error message")?

Comment: @Martin: I'd rather think this question is a helpful "near duplicate", because it's about the error resulting from the changed definition of ``\\``.

Comment: @Strong: I see that the same question appeared a second time. I assume this was a mistake, probably posting twice, so I've removed the duplicate. (For others, it was an exact copy of this one.)

Comment: @Martin: I'm not sure this is exactly a dupe, as the question here is to do with why a problem arises from the 'obvious' approach.

Comment: @Joseph: Mmm, the issue can be solved with the answers in the linked question, so it should be OK to close it as a duplicate after pointing out that the error can be fixed using the linked answers. I found the other question after I posted my answer. I personally don't mind if this question is closed or not.

Answer (score 5):

`\centering` changes the definition of `\\` which breaks inside `tabluar`s and `array`s. You need to add `\arraybackslash` afterwards to correct this. You also should define a new column type if you need this more often:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| C{2.5cm} | C{0.5cm} | C{2.5cm} |C{2.5cm} |C{2.5cm} |C{2.5cm} |}
\hline
Abc & Bcd & A long cell with text that wraps around and is centered & long cell with text  & AAAlong cell with text that wraps around and is centered & SSSlong cell with text that wraps around and is centered \\
1 & 3 & qw & qe & sad &11\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

See the related answer to [Center column with specifying width in table (tabular enviroment)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/center-column-with-specifying-width-in-table-tabular-enviroment/5020#5020) for advanced declarations which support line-breaks and hyphenation of the first word.

Comment: For narrow columns (such as the second one in the example code) it would be a good idea to add `\hspace{0pt}` to the column definition, to allow hyphenation of the first word.

Comment: Dear Martin. When I ran it, one error appeared: úndefined control sequence'for command ''newcolumntype''

Comment: @Strong: It works for me. `\newcolumntype` is defined by the `array` package.