# How do I right-align the last line of a justified paragraph?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, right-to-left

I want to wrap around text in a table cell; therefore I use the `p` option in the definition of `tabular`. However, I'm writing in Hebrew, so it aligns the last line to the left, instead of to the right. Can it be solved?

Comment: How about just issuing `\raggedleft` inside the cell?

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/center-column-with-specifying-width-in-table-tabular-enviroment

Comment: That works, thanks! However it doesn't change the spaces' lengths so the lines align up. I can live with that, but is it possible to easily do that?

Comment: lockstep: That only centers, doesn't it? Can't find a way to make it right to left.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want the entire cell contents to be justified, except the last line to be right justified (`\raggedleft`), you can use the following length settings ([original source](http://texhacks.blogspot.com/2011/01/center-last-line-in-paragraph.html)):

```
\leftskip=0pt plus .5fil
\rightskip=0pt plus -.5fil
\parfillskip=0pt plus .5fil
```

Here is a minimal working example (MWE) showing this in a `tabular` with `p{5cm}` column and some dummy text (provided by the [`lipsum` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum)):

[image: Right-to-left alignment in tabular]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\newcommand{\RTLpar}{% right-to-left paragraph alignment
  \leftskip=0pt plus .5fil%
  \rightskip=0pt plus -.5fil%
  \parfillskip=0pt plus .5fil%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}}
  \RTLpar%
  \lipsum[1]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}​
```

The MWE provides `\RTLpar` (short for "right-to-left paragraph") which modified these settings.

Comment: Anyone know the reason for the down vote on this? Seems to work fine for me.