# left align first line, right align second

Tags: paragraphs

I am typesetting a manually created author index. I want to put the name in the left margin and the page number in the right. I manage to right align the second line in cases where a linebreak is inserted because of long names.

The problem is that I would like to `\flushleft` the first line. But using  `\flushleft` breaks the alignment of the page number.

(To run with `xelatex`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\defaultfont}{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\latinfont}{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[Latin]{ucharclasses}
\setDefaultTransitions{\defaultfont}{}
\setTransitionsForLatin{\latinfont}{}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
  %%% Right align second line
  %%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43239/2483
  \leftskip=0pt plus 0.5fil%
  \rightskip=0pt plus -0.5fil%
  \parfillskip=0pt plus 0fil%
  \noindent Lasserre, Jean\hfill{}Vol. 3, 3743\par
  \noindent Logunov, Alexander (Александр Логунов)\hfill{}Vol.~2,~2361\par
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A variant of the “Bourbaki trick” in the TeXbook:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\newcommand{\entry}[2]{% #1 = author, #2 = ref
  \par\noindent{\RaggedRight
    #1%
    \nobreak\hfill\penalty50\hskip1em\null\nobreak
    \hfill\mbox{\normalfont(#2)}%
    \parfillskip=-\rightskip\par}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\entry{Lasserre, Jean}{Vol. 3, 3743}
\entry{Logunov, Alexander (Александр Логунов)}{Vol.~2,~2361}
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

The entry is typeset ragged right, but the `\parfillskip` will neutralize `\rightskip` in the last or unique line.

At least 1em is left between the name and the reference.

[image]