# Align columns in multiple subfigure tables in figure environment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, floats, subfloats

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Main figure}

\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\caption{Table 1}
%Table 1
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\toprule
Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3 \\
\midrule
Blablabla & Bliblablabla & Blublasdad \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\caption{Table 2}
%Table 2
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\toprule
Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3 \\
\midrule
A & B & C\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{subfigure}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Which gives me this:

[image: Resulting output]

The tables are of different widths. I would like for the columns in both tables to be aligned pair-wise with one another (i.e. "Header 3" column of table 1 is aligned with that of table 2), and have them all centered. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You could define a `newcolumntype` using the [`array`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/array) package to make a `centered` column that accepts a `width`

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
```

as demonstrated in [Center column with specifying width in table (tabular enviroment)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/center-column-with-specifying-width-in-table-tabular-enviroment)

I've also used the [`calc`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/calc) package for the `\widthof` command.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \caption{Main figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \caption{Table 1}
        %Table 1
        \begin{tabular}{|C{\widthof{Blablabla}}|C{\widthof{Bliblablabla}} |C{\widthof{Blublasdad}}|}
            \toprule
            Header 1  & Header 2     & Header 3   \\
            \midrule
            Blablabla & Bliblablabla & Blublasdad \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \caption{Table 2}
        %Table 2
        \begin{tabular}{|C{\widthof{Blablabla}}|C{\widthof{Bliblablabla}} |C{\widthof{Blublasdad}}|}
            \toprule
            Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3 \\
            \midrule
            A        & B        & C        \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

As a final note, the `booktabs` author (and a few folks on this site) would recommend against using vertical lines in your `tabular` environments- of course, this is personal preference, but for reference have a look at [Why not use vertical lines ('|') in a tabular?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40542/why-not-use-vertical-lines-in-a-tabular)

Comment: I used vertical lines to have the width of the columns be more clear visually. I don't display them in my document. Is there another way that doesn't involve me inputting the text in the \widthof function? I have many tables with many rows, and it's not a priori clear which row will have the largest element for a given column. I need something that takes the width of the column, as calculated automatically by the system.

Comment: I'm working on a `pgfplotstable` idea...

Answer (score 3):

Probably I would just choose the widths in advance as in

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,caption,subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\caption{Main figure}

\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\centering
\caption{Table 1}
%Table 1
\begin{tabular}{|*3{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.25\linewidth}|}}
\toprule
Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3 \\
\midrule
Blablabla & Bliblablabla & Blublasdad \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip

\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\centering
\caption{Table 2}
%Table 2
\begin{tabular}{|*3{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.25\linewidth}|}}
\toprule
Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3 \\
\midrule
A & B & C\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{subfigure}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

However if you definitely want single line entries and the widths chosen dynamically thaen you can make it a single table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,caption,subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\caption{Main figure}
\centering

%Table 1
\begin{tabular}{|*3{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.25\linewidth}|}}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{%
\makebox[0pt][c]{\parbox{\textwidth}{%
\subcaption{Table 1}
}}}\\
\toprule
Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3 \\
\midrule
Blablabla & Bliblablabla & Blublasdad \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{%
\makebox[0pt][c]{\parbox{\textwidth}{%
\bigskip
\subcaption{Table 2}
}}}\\
\toprule
Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3 \\
\midrule
A & B & C\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}


\end{table}

\end{document}
```