# Center table by end of cell

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I want to be able to center my table, but align the center by the end of the first cell. Currently just using the `\begin{center}` command i am able to center the table but i would rather the table be centered based off the end of the first cell and not by the average center of the table.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\begin{document}  

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{r | l}
I am some really long text & 10pt \\ 
I am also really long & 12pt \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Gets a table that is centered, but i would rather it went
"I am some really long text {center here} 10pt.

Edit: The idea i'm kind of looking for can be seen in the way that you can [align equations](http://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Aligning_equations_with_amsmath) at any point.

Comment: Just to clarify: you want the vertical rule separating the columns to be centered on the page? Rather than as it is currently with the  full contents evenly centered on the page. Correct?

Comment: That's exactly it, and much better worded than my original question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just a variant of Poul's answer. Instead array package can use tabularx package and define new column types R and L. There is no need to measure width of columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|R|L|}
    I am some really long text & 10pt \\
    I am also really long      & 12pt 
  \end{tabularx}
\end{center}  
\hrulefill.\hrulefill % just for visual check
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why Chris (cmhughes) deleted his answer. But, for this simple job, no need of loading a heavy package like `tabularx`. Without it, this is how it is done.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth
                                                   -2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth
                                                   -2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{R|L}
    aaaa    I am some really long text & I am some really long text aaaa\\
        I am also really long      & I am also really long     \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\hrulefill.\hrulefill % just for visual check
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 nice work, Harish! yours is much better than mine, I'm very happy to vote for you :)

Answer (score 4):

Obviously, extra columns could be inserted on either (sub)tabular to extend the table leftward or rightward, respectively, even as the dividing line between the halves remains centered.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\begin{document}  

\begin{center}
\makebox[0pt][r]{%
\begin{tabular}{r |}
I am some really long text\\ 
I am also really long\\ 
\end{tabular}%
}%
\makebox[0pt][l]{%
\begin{tabular}{| l}
 10pt \\ 
 12pt \\ 
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Steven's answer will work, but if you'd like to avoid breaking up the tabular (at the cost of needing to specify widths):

Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5020/21344), we can use facilities of the `array` package to define new column types `L{<width}`, `C{<width>}`, `R{<width>}` for which an explicit width may be declared. Choose this `<width>` to fit the widest content in all columns and set it for all columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}  
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{R{1.7in} | L{1.7in}}
    I am some really long text & 10pt \\ 
    I am also really long      & 12pt \\ 
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\hrulefill.\hrulefill % just for visual check
\end{document}
```

[image]